# Are we allowed to ask/remind the OP to accept answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I've started to see this happen quite often of late. And this is usually done by users whose rep ranges between 200 to 2k reputation.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24522806/1223045) again today and wondered if we are allowed to do so. It does seem like this sort of activity shouldn't be encouraged but who am I to say and hence the question.

EDIT: Ok, the person who posted the answer deleted his comment asking for acceptance of the answer...This practice seems to be gaining momentum.

Comment: seems nothing stops some one from doing it technically, Personally I don't support this (looks cheap). A good answer will be supported by many irrespective of it being accepted or not.

Comment: Yep, "cheap" was the word I was looking for especially if it comes from a low rep user

Comment: This is probably very much a duplicate question...

Comment: @Cupcake Sorry about that. I did go through the list of suggested duplicates that popped up while creating this question but I didn't find a suitable match

Comment: Here's a related MSE post, but I'm still looking around for an MSO version too: [Comments saying “thank you” remind OP to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177292/163250).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I sometimes see the polite "hints" about accepting the answer added as comments. There's nothing wrong with it, IMHO. I never do it, though. Well, I did it once, but felt weird about it. I'm aware that there's more to it than just asking for points. It's useful for other readers to see the accepted answer clearly marked. And just as importantly, people will sometimes search for questions without accepted answers, and they get a lot of false positives with all the questions that were solved, but not marked.

Still, to me it felt like I was begging for something, and decided that it wasn't worth it. After all, you don't get a free Ferrari when you reach a certain point level. ;) So I just know that I don't get the "accepted" score for probably at least 1/3 of my answers where I provided the solution that the poster was looking for. Often times they will leave comments saying that, so I know that my answer was on target. That's good enough for me. I always appreciate it when posters accept answers, but I know that it's voluntary, and I respect that.

Comment: This pretty much echos my thoughts on the subject. So I guess there is no hard and fast rule against it but it would seem best to not ask for it.

Answer (score 24):

Actually, IMHO, I think that we have to differentiate in this matter. While it might look odd or cheap for some, encouraging new users to accept an answer seems fine to me under the following conditions:

- It is a neutral comment suggesting to accept an answer, if the question was answered
- The OP has made clear in his comments that the problem was solved

Example of what I think is **ok**:

"If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references."

Example of what I consider **cheap**:

"Accept my answer, yo!"

After all, how would new users be supposed to learn, if noone beats them to it?

Personally I do even do that when coming across questions I haven't answered...

Comment: Neutral comment is fine. It's the answerer asking for acceptance which seems inappropriate

Comment: No, if it is still a neutral comment it seems fine to me. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: "please make sure to accept an answer" What do I do if I'm the only answer?

Comment: *"OP has made clear in comments that problem was solved"* is a non-starter, because many low-rep OPs simply don't leave any follow-up comments at all. With those users, the absence of complaints is the only evidence we can have that they solved things. The worse ones go on to splatter the site with near-duplicate questions. (And the worst ones delete their questions after they get an answer, often with excuses *"I'm not supposed to post my employer's code/ exam question/ coding challenge cheating/ evidence of plagiary"*. Oh and then they reincarnate under another handle if they get banned.)

Comment: ...also there are some OPs who post stuff like *"It's still broken"* or *"You didn't give me a solution"* hours/days/weeks after you affirmatively gave them a solution, sometimes due to didn't read it/ language familiarity/ can't use their own IDE/ didn't understand why it was an answer etc etc. But there are also OPs who legitimately can't post code, and whose symptoms are complex and vague, and interact with other known-issues. So I'd change your phrase to "*the absence of any valid objections or negative comments"*. I'm avoiding throwing in *"valid verifiable objections"* for that reason.