# Is it okay to request a newbie user to accept and upvote?

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer

There are multiple questions related to this case - [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262209/are-we-allowed-to-ask-remind-the-op-to-accept-answers/262218#262218) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297597/what-to-do-with-user-asking-for-upvote-and-accept/297598#297598).  Some of them suggests that it is okay to comment with the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  But, I have my doubts due to the following reasons.

Today, I flagged an accept request from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70908358/0-variables-how-can-i-fix-it/70908516?noredirect=1#comment125354693_70908516) as "No longer needed" and the comment got deleted.  The OP commented that his comments are *"non-offensive, non-inflammatory comments (which are within general guidelines) are marked and deleted with no discussion"* and also mentioned *"... there is no way to doctrinally advise new users of yet-unknown etiquette"*.  I agree with the OP's comments, but I flagged it because of a recent moderator message to me.  Some of the contents in the message are:

[image]

Most of my comments related to the acceptance is *"Please consider to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) link"* and it is often directed towards newbies.

After receiving this message, I don't comment anything related to votes nor with the SO link.  My question is if a newbie doesn't know the rules, is it still okay to comment with the link or not?

Comment: @cigien No, that is still not clear, because the moderator response to me was `"Do not leave any more comments asking for users to upvote or accept your answers.  There should be no discussion of votes in comments whatsoever"`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused by. It's ok in general to mention accepting answers to new users (as mentioned in the suggested duplicate). If you, specifically, have been instructed by a site moderator not to do this anymore, you don't do it any more. That's all there is to it really. I have no idea *why* you've been told to stop, but that's something you have to take up with the mod team.

Comment: @cigien I read the moderator comments as "under no circumstances" that is including the newbies as well.  I used to comment with the SO link to accept.  If the mods have such an issue, they should clarify it here

Comment: I don't know if mods will discuss this publicly, but I suppose you can ask. FWIW, your interpretation seems correct to me. Under no circumstances should you leave any more comments asking users to accept or upvote your answers. So I'm not even sure what further clarification you're looking for.

Comment: @cigien that is why I am not commenting anymore.  But, when I flagged the request on the link, the user got disturbed quoting that it maybe okay to comment when it is newbie.   I want to get a clear answer.

Comment: I did send my response to moderators, but they didn't respond back.  So, I am posting this on meta

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the moderator message. *You*, specifically have been instructed not to leave such comments, that's all. In general, it's ok for users to mention accepts and stuff like that, so your comments to that other user aren't really correct. There is no general rule about never commenting about accepts, it's specific to you.

Comment: @cigien In that case, it is bias.  I understand the rules to be same for all members and not different for different people

Comment: The rules are the same for everyone. Obviously, I don't know the details, but I'm guessing you crossed the line by leaving too many such comments, too often. Several answers on the suggested duplicate mention that you shouldn't be pushy, or harass users, by repeatedly leaving such comments.

Comment: @cigien So in your view, I lost the privilege to comment because of leaving too many? comments with links to newbies? If that is the case they should have mentioned in the message.  From the email, I thought they are discussing in general about the usage of comments

Comment: Like I said, it's just a guess. If you want clarification about a mod message, then messaging the mod team is the best approach, as you've done. Be patient, they'll get around to responding eventually.

Comment: Actually, no, the policy as far as I recall was to delete such comments on site, which is also supported by the auto-deletion single-flag check being in-built. The caveat in the guidance is for an extremely narrow use case (no accept ever). I personally consider this an unethical thing if it involves one's own posts as it is a conflict of interest.

Comment: See: [one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297597/what-to-do-with-user-asking-for-upvote-and-accept#comment210255_297597), [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403393/11407695). Both responses are made by mods, and I strongly support the message: those comments are attempts to influence voting patterns, and should be flagged as NLN on sight.

Comment: [Three](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306650/11407695), also mod. There is a *clear* and unambiguous policy: those comments are not ok - you did the correct thing for flagging (and mods sending you the messafge if they noticed you are  posting them too often). Sure, that's not a big deal if someone leaves them from time to time, especially with a noble goal of educating a user, but it does not change the general policy.

Comment: @akrun the 3 top voted mod answers on the issue say it's OK depending on the case, one of the most relevant is [this answer by Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999). It's frequent for users to comment: *"Perfect answer, solved my problem, thanks."* and not bother to accept or vote (they might even have been around for years and be oblivious nevertheless). So in those cases a friendly reminder is OK (and there's strong consensus backing that assertion).

Comment: @akrun besides [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) and [the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) also say users are supposed to accept and upvote answers that solve their problem perfectly (there's nothing wrong with reminding/pointing users to official SE guidelines).

Comment: @bad_coder Thanks, yes, I did go through some links and the consensus seems to be acceptable, though in some cases it says not to comment as OlegValter mentioned i.e. when there is a conflict of interest.  I posted this because I was not sure if the response from moderators were exclusive for me or is in general.

Comment: @akrun you likely simply left them too often (or on your posts primarily as the msg seems to suggest) - they are certainly no crime, but they do add noise to posts *and* are of dubious effectiveness at best (I will do a query to substantiate or disprove when I have time, it's an interesting topic)

Comment: @OlegValter the comments have (mostly) been purged, so let me save you the trouble: At least 4-8%  of their total 82514 comments (at the time of writing, including all deleted) revolve around upvoting and/or accepting. A quick manual search on common terms, admittedly with some overlap, indicates at least 4-5000 (!) of these comments. A non-negligible amount also asks for upvotes.

Comment: @Zoe jeez, that's... quite a lot, thank you for the insight! I can totally see why that would be considered problematic. One thing I will still likely spend some time researching is how actually *effective* those are - one of the common defences for posting comments requesting upvotes/accepts is that they remind users of the functionality, so it got me thinking - do they *really*?

Comment: @Zoe But my question is about what is right or wrong.  Is this only exclusive against me i.e. not to comment about upvotes, but others can still ask/request for acceptance when the question asked is a newbie.  If that is the case, it is biased and wrong.  The link in the question as Oleg mentioned had a conflict of interest.  So, I flagged that as "No longer needed".

Comment: @OlegValter if they are going by the statistics, I can only say that I also looked at the metaposts in the link which suggests that requesting to accept/voting when it is a newbie is ok.  So, previously, I do comment in that way until I received the moderator message.

Comment: @akrun just saying that I see how such a number of comments could be considered problematic by the mod team. Also, as I linked in my other comments, the "those are ok" is far from being the consensus amongst mods - if anything, there are more of those who consider them *just* noise to be removed on sight. That does not make the course you took a big issue (if it was, you would likely be suspended for some time in addition to the message), just that the team would like you to stop doing it as they view it as causing more trouble than it is worth. And you seem to be doing the right thing now -

Comment: - flagging such comments as NLN. If you are concerned that the user whose comment you got deleted is upset and thinks they are in the right - don't, there are not (for the reasons I indicated above). There are some who hold the opinion that it is OK to remind about the rules, but it is not what the general policy about these comments is (as linked), it is more of a "well, there is a use case where they are probably not harmful"

Comment: @OlegValter I would say that newbie case is just an excuse.  Because if newbies know how to find SO, and posts a question, they would in time understand about upvoting/accepting.  In the last couple of days, I found many newbies without even mentioning anything, accepted answer.  Some people don't, but that includes experienced users as well.  They just don't think it is important or have other reasons.

Comment: @OlegValter I flagged this specific case as NLN only because the question could be easily closed as a typo/duplicate (the `,` replaced by `&` and it solves) and the exact issue was solved already in the comments.  So, if someone writes an answer and then makes a request to accept, it is definitely a conflict of interest.

Comment: @akrun yes, that was definitely a conflict of interest, and you did right in flagging it as NLN - not only the answerer went against the guidelines of treating typo/duplixate questions, they (regardless of the intent) went as far as requesting votes on their own post.

Comment: @akrun I don't buy that mod message because I've pinged dozens of high rep users asking them why they didn't accept an excellent answer (in threads where I had no participation but enough expertise to know I was looking at the perfect unaccepted answer) and the OPs said: *"Thanks for reminding me, I totally forgot about that!"* (a recent case was a reminder to a 6 figure rep I know in real life). The site is made better by an answer being accepted, because it reduces entropy and makes things more organized.

Comment: @bad_coder I also had noticed similar instances regarding experienced users.   With regards to newbies, often I get "Thank you, this solved perfectly" messages which prompt me to comment to the SO link for accept.  I understand that this will in someway influence the users to accept and thereby I gain points.  I totally agree with the moderators though - this is a forum and the persons who spend their time, energy, and their knowlege should do selflessly without even thinking about any reps at all!

Comment: @akrun and the perfect counter-example are the countless thousands of comments (that are not deleted - nor are there any cases of people raising controversy over those comments) saying: *"This should be the accepted answer."*

Comment: @akrun in truth, the overzealous claim *"no comments about accepts/votes are permitted"* is entirely false, it subverts (and perverts) fundamental system mechanics, it also goes against historical consensus and company guidelines. What's more, it should be put into the broader perspective of the +170 SE sites, on the vast majority of the network such comments are NOT frowned upon (not by mods nor users) if they correspond to justice - of rewarding and recognizing the right solution and its author. (Notice arguments against are made in *bad faith* and being simplistic lack valid elaboration.)

Comment: @bad_coder It is not clear whether that is only applicable to me or not as the moderator message is in contradiction to the general consensus in many of the links

Comment: @akrun then let us try to clarify (using the classic terminology): Since it's inception SO's guidance has been not [the letter of the law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_and_spirit_of_the_law) but its spirit; Shog9 synthesized it by saying: *"We can't codify rules for every conduct"*. The argument made against you is statistical, and thus a gross approximation that doesn't care if your comments were warranted, justified and beneficial. This represent a rupture with previous moderation practices that cared to evaluate cases, it has also tones of a database driven persecutory practice.

Comment: @akrun the argument made against you is ludicrous, because with 33k answers making 4k comments about accepting represents 12% and anyone with SO experience knows the percentage of OPs who routinely ignore valid answers is much higher than that. (Any reasonable reading would consider that percentage of comments as routine maintenance/curation that simply needs to be done with uninformed/forgetful/irresponsible OPs.)

Comment: @bad_coder Its ok.  If they feel that I am unfairly manipulating the system for those, let them do it.

Comment: @bad_coder Just to quote a recent newbie comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70917346/avoid-repetition-in-summarise-using-across-or-tidyverse/70917444?noredirect=1#comment125372099_70917444) `That worked like a charm! Thank you so much!!!!! Exactly what I was looking for! – 
user17168096`. With this constraint, I can't comment anything below that.  The newbie definitely doesn't know the rules and we can only assume he/she had to learn it by themselves

Comment: @akrun absolutely!! There are lots of use cases, e.g. users who only log in 2 times per year might find the accept comment useful when they come back (in 6-8 months). I've left such comments in threads with unaccepted answers by core devs (who better to answer and to see their participation rewarded and encouraged...?!)

Comment: @bad_coder with that moderator message, I cannot comment anymore.  If i do, I know they will suspend me.  I was previously suspended for deleting an answer I posted and then reposting same answer which I didn't know that it is a big issue.

Comment: @akrun someone like you with 33k answers (divide by 365 times years of participation) is certain to do something wrong on occasion (with that volume of participation it's unavoidable). I think you should consider using the SE contact form (that's the advice I've been given by community managers). But, the issue of the comments isn't settled - not here, nor network wide. There's a strong possibility that mods collectively don't agree with the procedure in this case (I don't) and it's just an individual action that happened. Don't be afraid, I interacted with mods and many are good people.

Comment: @bad_coder Based on my previous interaction - one time they suspended me and I contacted SO directly with an appeal.  Then the mod involved said that he/she took the action without going over the details as the comments were removed.

Comment: @akrun a middle ground for a prolific user like yourself is writing a general question and posting it on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) that's the epicenter of discussion where the network mods and staff come together. Sometimes -as you can see in this thread- it's just not possible to have a sensible discussion on MSO. If you take the care of writing a well developed set of argument that preempts most of the simplistic counter-arguments it should be well received. Also, because it's not a dup and the statistical argument made against you is unprecedented and deserves broader discussion

Comment: @bad_coder the issue with writing a question by me is that if I write anything, it would be downvoted here or heavily criticized.  There is a biased view against high rep users (from my experience with previous postings).  If I look at the number of downvotes, I am not sure about the reason.  Maybe because people think it is a duplicate question though it is not.  My point is based on the mods assertion on the message and the meta posts conflicting advise.  Here, I didn't blame anything.  I was just trying to understand whether it is ok to flag with NLN or not.

Comment: Who are you serving, by reminding users that they can accept an answer? Accepted answers are no longer pinned to the top, so there's no real... value in it other than rewarding the answerer. It's always going to look like a selfish action. It is no longer needed/useful.

Comment: @KevinB IMHO performance psychology suggests for `deliberate practice` and deliberate practise one can't do it without giving an incentive to the brain.  Here, obviously (for me) the incentive is game points (which had no value otherwise whatsoever).  I consider this as a game to cheat my brain to do the deliberate practise -> perform better -> on a particular topic.  Thus, if we say that things should be all voluntary without any incentive, then people will lose some interest

Comment: @KevinB the check mark is still useful, just because answers aren't pinned it did not render the check mark useless (something that happens on a per-site basis, there are sites that still pin the accepted answer including this one, MSO!!). If readers and users want the check mark and like the check mark it's not only system design but user decision, no one is in a place to say otherwise or make that call. (As for the moderator action taken here it's not consensual, there is no indication that way - in fact the most relevant historical indications are to the contrary).

Comment: it is "useful" for attracting more upvotes, that's certainly true. I am well aware that child metas don't have it pinned, and that other sites may not have it pinnned, however we're clearly discussing SO here, where the warning was issued.

Comment: @KevinB it's usefulness is much broader by narrowing search results for unaccepted answers and signalling with high correlation threads that are solved satisfactorily. (And no, we are discussing statistical database driven coercion, warning, and threat - something the company never condoned.)

Comment: @KevinB  Suppose we cannot say to the newbie about SO voting/acceptance and if the newbie continues asking questions.  In the long run, he would get very little response because people look at the profiles and judge that the OP is not interested in accepting/upvoting.  The reality is that the OP may not even know the rules.  In that case, who is going to inform the user about the rules

Comment: @akrun that used to be a problem, back when "acceptance rate" was a status on the profile. Those days are long gone.

Comment: @KevinB Still considering that every accept tag gets 15 points and this is very useful when the 200 point cap/daily gets over (from a game perspective)

Comment: well, again, that's selfish reasoning, that's wanting the user to accept an answer, because you want rep... not because it's useful for any other purpose. That's why people are pushing against it, whether that reasoning is correct or otherwise. If the user needs to be informed that accepting answers is a thing, the system should be doing it.

Comment: @KevinB one of the major reasons why SO is so popular is because of its game format and point system.  selflessness can be written, but very difficult to practise because everything we do have at least an iota of selfishness

Comment: @akrun again, I've read many of KevinB's comments and they frequently are only half-true or partial. Recent indications from community managers are that voting is essential and a it's a major concern that users answering are duly rewarded for their efforts. Hence the check is still relevant especially at a time when repositories are maturing and the userbase providing answers needs to renew itself. (Hence I don't consider any of KevinB's arguments here valid because they don't address, nor try, any of the concerns voiced by the CMs, hence the company. Disregarding valid arguments isn't valid.)

Comment: @akrun the argument of selflessness is fallacious, for 2 reaons: 1st the statistical argument doesn't hold if you're reminding users to accept other people's answers. 2nd SE has always relied on gamification to motive beneficial action, thus the emphasis is exclusively on objective benefit/justice of a given action towards the community and individual users, selflessness doesn't enter this specific debate. (OlegValter is a PhD in philosophy, I'd raise the bar to his level analyses, random punditry -that is prevalent and sometimes, regrettably, dominates MSO- holds little factual interest.)

Comment: The only reason you're reminding users to accept *other* people's answers is because asking for them to accept yours is plainly against the rules.

Comment: @KevinB Your suggestion is that I can comment to accept/votes for others and not for myself.  If that is the case, it can be misused as well - people in groups can have an understanding to follow the rules and comment

Comment: no, my suggestions is to not comment at all on the subject. If you think the system isn't doing enough to inform users that they can accept answers, make a meta post asking for that feature to be improved. IMO, using "an" answer instead of "my" answer is just rule dodging.

Comment: @KevinB I am not sure whether they mention about the voting rules/acceptance when a person joins.  Some people won't read any of those popup messages while joining as they just want to quickly post a question and get an answer

Comment: Sure, however, why can't the system inform the user the same way your comment does, if your comment is so much more effective?

Comment: @KevinB I think it depends on how the system wants it to work.  If the users feel that they can only post a question only after making sure they read all the rules (in a stringent way) they will post their question in another forum.  From an users perspective, their primary goal is to get the solution ASAP and not read/understand the rules of the forum

Comment: @KevinB Also, according to research, we get 11 million sensory inputs per second, of which only 40 can be focused and of which only 4 can be remembered.  So, if an user reads the system manual a month back, the probability of him/her remembering some information that is not useful to them is very low

Comment: i mean, none of that matters. If what you're doing is more effective, the system can do that too in an unbiased way.

Comment: @KevinB I would say the system should send messages to newbie until he/she does their first accept/upvote.

Comment: @akrun actually... users posting ill-researched, broad, dupllicate, or discussion-style qusstions more on forums and *not* on SO is in everyone's best interest. It is not like we have a shotage of those, we have an over-supply of  such posts and diminishing answerer base that are frustrated with having to spend an ever increasing amount of time on finding actually interesting questions.

Comment: As for system notifications - yeah, this is a thing that the system *should* do, not us, I agree with @KevinB on that. In a better world, an algorithm taking into account vote/accept rate would determine whether to start reminding the user about the functionality, but alas...

Comment: @OlegValter that is true.  Usually it is newbie questions that are illresearched, duplicates.  But, I had seen some excellent questions by newbies and very poor questions by experienced people as well.  If we regulate the comments for accept/upvotes, naturally the ill-researched questions would be less answered (although we have to consider where the SO stands on this case - based on the meta posts, SO seems to be lenient towards getting more traffic in the expense of quality posts)

Answer (score 13):

I obviously can't speak for the mod in question, but my take is that it's ok to ask new users to accept *an* answer (preferably with a link to the relevant MSO post on how accepting works), but asking them to accept *your* answer in particular is a little more sketchy.

I certainly don't agree with asking for upvotes (especially on your own post) though; I'm somewhat uncomfortable with asking people to vote either way on any particular post, because that seems contrary to the purpose of content rating.