# Personal attack by a moderator, with no accountability

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators, behavior

Update:

- I've toned down the language in the title and the body of this post. You can see the original in the edit history, if desired, and there are references to it in the comments. The original wording was a reflection of my exasperation, but it was needlessly incendiary - my apologies.
- Perhaps needless to say, it is *my* perception that what occurred constitutes a personal attack, but I invite you to see for yourself.

---

To be clear:

- What this post is *not* about:

  - Discussing the merits of improving the existing mechanism for encouraging new user to "do the right thing" - *to me, this is well worth discussing, but separately*.

    - *Update*: More specifically, this post was therefore also never about discussing the behavior that led to the moderator warning.
  - Identifying a particular member of the moderator team (my original attempt to ask them to identify themselves in a private exchange notwithstanding).
  - Having a *respectful* disagreement, including the choice to exit a conversation - which, needless to say, is perfectly acceptable.
- What this post *is* about:

  - Sparing other users the treatment described below.
  - Ensuring accountability in private conversations with users.

---

- I received a private message from the Stack Overflow Moderation Team containing what I presume to be a form letter (canned message) asking me not to use comments to ask users to accept answers. (Even if it wasn't a form letter, it was a calmly worded message that made specific points, some of which I disputed in my response).
- I wrote a response, which can be summarized as follows (but I invite you to study the transcript to see if this summary is apt):

  - I agreed to stop posting these comments, because I agree that the guidance my comments were meant to provide are better provided by a mechanism built into the site.

    > Fair enough, I'll stop
  - The following thoughts were - literally - labeled *asides*, because I was cognizant that it was a *separate discussion*:

    - I explained my motivation for posting these comments.
    - I voiced my concerns about characterizing whether users should accept answers as "completely optional" vs. *voluntary* with a view toward *guiding* them to the behavior that benefits the community at large.
    - I stated that I was unaware that a mechanism already existed (I've never seen it) and that, given my experience with the results of posting my comments, the existing mechanism strikes me as inadequate, and inquired whether improvements were underway.
    - In short: it was an invitation to reach a shared understanding about how (new) users should be guided toward behavior that benefits the community as a whole (whether or not the exchange at hand was the right place to *continue* this discussion is irrelevant).

The (non-canned) response that followed I can only describe as a mixture of the following, in no particular order:

- assumptions of ill intent
- speculation about motivation
- casting aspersions
- gratuitous threats  [update: a repeat warning was justified, given that I didn't make it clear enough that I would comply; even so, the wording strikes me as incendiary]

A few quotes (again, I invite you to study the transcript):

> You've been around long enough (...)

> Stop trying to bring it back. [I had no idea what I was trying to "bring back", and certainly didn't ask for it]

> Frankly, reading your reply to this message gives the impression that you have developed quite some entitlement complex

> that just solidifies our concerns about you bullying users

> Further comments of that kind will be deleted upon sight, with no notification, and may lead to sanctions against your account.

In short: a personal attack, with no accountability (no response was received after my calling for accountability).

*Update*: **On further reflection, I realize I must show accountability myself:**

- My first response was not as neutral as I believed it to be, so I can now see my part in this escalation - see [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417618/45375) for details.

**Transcript**:

- For the record: here's the - non-public - link to the original exchange: https://stackoverflow.com/users/message/86591
- Publicly viewable copy:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE1Rr.png

Comment: The way that first quote is presented is a bit selective. The full quote "You've been around long enough to remember that accept rate used to be shown publicly." has a very different connotation to just "You've been around long enough (...)".

Comment: Can you describe here what you think is "unprofessional"? It is part of a moderator's job to assess users' motivations in terms of actions they have taken on the site. No one likes being called out, which is why we do it in private, rather than in public. It appears you think it is unprofessional (or even a "gratuitous threat"?) to warn you that future comments of this nature will be deleted on sight, but I don't see how it is either of those. It's an attempt to be clear. If your reply had left it as "Fair enough, I'll stop", as you imply here, there would have been no need for a mod response.

Comment: @HenryEcker, I don't think that is relevant (but it's good to have the full quote now), because (a) I never knew nor do I care whether an accept rate was ever shown publicly and (b) the point is that an unfounded _assumption_ was made that I would know and that that (non-existing) knowledge factored into my behavior.

Comment: As I gather it, you appear to be *most* upset that a moderator made the assumption that you knew about the old "accept rate" feature and that you were trying to "bring it back". That was, admittedly, an assumption that the moderator made, in an attempt to try to understand your mindset that accepting answers is necessary/important, and that any reasonable attempt on your part to encourage this is intrinsically good. All of those premises are wrong, so how should we proceed? Just tell you that you are wrong? We try to understand the motivations of users so we can best address their concerns.

Comment: @CodyGray, I don't think it's worth focusing on just _one_ of the unprofessional comments highlighted in this post (it was Henry Ecker who happened to call out that particular one). As for your questions: I feel that without a shared understanding that unprofessional conduct has occurred, there is no benefit in continuing this conversation.

Comment: Meh, other than perhaps the "entitlement complex" comment I think they were civil enough (and even in context that makes sense). You're making this far bigger than it is.

Comment: How does an accepted answer benefit the whole community? Is this a "when an answer is selected, then the question is solved/done" mindset? If "no", how would the "whole community" benefit? If "yes", would that make sense in an area which keeps evolving and needs constant updates, especially on a site which gives less and less meaning/importance to the fact that an answer has been accepted?

Comment: @Tom, to recap from the question: "What this post is _not_ about:
Discussing the merits of improving the existing mechanism for encouraging new user to 'do the right thing'" - I don't know how to state it any clearer: this is about the _tone and attitude of the response_, not about the substance of the argument, which is an entirely separate matter.

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't trying to highlight a specific reason, I was just noting that the way it was quoted changed the connotation of the statement. You present an issue about tone and attitude, but my questions is: what would a resolution look like? Do you have a system for accountability in mind? What mechanism  do you think would be reasonable to put in place to ensure the level of professionalism you were expecting? Do you have an actionable request of the mod team or the SO community?

Comment: Just as a note (and not saying this was part of the accountability you were looking for) but moderator messages were [made anonymous due to real life retribution experienced by SE mods due to their actions as a moderator.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283725/1099857)

Comment: @HenryEcker, understood re anonymity - as stated, I'm not looking to identify a particular moderator, but I do hope for accountability - and I have no easy answer; looking for a solution _together_ has to start with a shared understanding that something went awry, and that seems to be the first stumbling block. Fair enough for calling out that one quote: I don't think your characterization of the abbreviation changing the connotation is valid, as argued in my previous comment, but I don't think we need to come to an understanding there - all the information is there for others to see.

Comment: My 2cts, but the "Mechanism" mentioned in "*I stated that I was unaware that a mechanism already existed (I've never seen it) and that, given my experience with the results of posting my comments, the existing mechanism strikes me as inadequate, and inquired whether improvements were underway.*" has definitely not/never been implemented for the small Tag ([tag:imacros]) I answer, ah-ah...! Once every 3 months I get a User accepting an Answer... (I usually make +[50-70]-Rep per year, depending on "good"/"bad" years, ah-ah...!)

Comment: The canned message was perfect. The follow-up, less so, and was probably best left out altogether. I believe the crux of the matter lies on the closing lines, which seem to me ill-advised in a couple of ways. But all in all, the whole message could have been avoided. Nothing new was brought to bear, and the message was not helpful in deescalating (or simply avoiding escalation) of the situation. Around here, we often repeat the importance of "moving on" when encountering disagreement. I think that the mod reply reads like a failure in that regard.

Comment: Regarding "accountability", meh. Anonymity is there because we need it, because humans. For mod accountability, we already have meta and raising additional flags. The system is not perfect, but maybe it does not need to be either.

Comment: I appreciate your levelheaded comments, @yivi.
Re accountability: fair enough, perhaps this post here is all that is needed, possibly serving as a reference point for users with similar complaints in the future.
 I agree that the closing lines are the primary problem, but a belligerent and condescending attitude permeates the whole response.
Indeed the response _was_ the escalation, given that I had promised to stop, and, in good faith, had tried to start a dialog about
properly solving the perceived problem my behavior at issue had tried to address.

Comment: @yivi I might agree with you if mklement0's reply has consisted exclusively (or nearly so) of what he saw fit to quote here: "Fair enough, I'll stop". However, the bulk of his reply consisted of reasons why he disagreed with the initial message, which served to almost completely undermine (or at least carve out exceptions to) the indication that he would stop. At that point, a reply is almost required, if for no other reason than to avoid giving the signal of a moderator's acquiescence to or agreement with the objections/exceptions raised in the reply.

Comment: A moderator message reply is not an appropriate place to "start a dialog about properly solving the perceived problem". A moderator message reply like that, in our experience, strongly suggests that a user did not take our initial message seriously and has no plans to actually stop what they have been requested to stop. There is no evidence of contrition, only a belligerent posture that you were correct to have been doing so all along due to perceived failures in the system. Whether that was *your specific* intention, I can't say; only provide context of what has been our consistent experience

Comment: @CodyGray As a general rule, replies like this are best ignored, IMO, not engaged. When warning a user about undesirable conduct, there are two possible outcomes: they stop that behavior, or they don't. If they don't stop, additional steps may be required, and they were already adequately warned by the first canned message. If they do change their behavior, then the response to the warning becomes irrelevant. But in any case, if one chooses to reply, one should try to be extra careful in replying in a way that would help reach a peaceful resolution to the matter.

Comment: @CodyGray, I quoted that part because it mattered most; also note that it _concluded_ my response (aside from asking about improvements). There was no belligerence in my initial response - only arguments you may disagree with, and they were all in service to highlighting the real problem, which isn't my behavior (again, you may disagree). Fair enough that it wasn't the right place to start this discussion - telling me _that_ would have helped, instead of the vitriol that ensued.

Comment: And to be clear, @CodyGray: Even if the perception was that my commitment to stop was ambiguous, unclear, ... and that an explicit follow-up was therefore needed, it is the _tone and wording_ of the follow-up at hand that is at issue.

Comment: I very much disagree; no matter how many times I re-read your message, I do not see it as fundamentally agreeing to stop the discussed behavior. Rather, I see it as an attempt to re-litigate what a moderator had already told you, in no uncertain terms, to stop. Again, I'll allow that this impression is colored by the type of replies that we generally receive from users to moderator messages, as well as the fact that a mod message reply is not the right place to start a general, unrelated discussion. But, yes, we fundamentally disagree that the problem was not your behavior. It was.

Comment: In fact, that is *precisely the point*: your reply to the mod message suggested that you did not think your behavior was the problem, and you *continue* to suggest as such, which means that the initial mod message did not have the desired effect, which was to advise you that your behavior was problematic and needed to stop, with no exceptions. When users refuse to listen to moderators and reply with excuses that attempt to justify their behavior, the replies tend to get sterner. I still don't see anything wrong with the tone and wording, other than that you disagree with its characterization.

Comment: @CodyGray, I worded my previous comment _here_ poorly: I meant to say that the larger problem _that we could move on to tackling_ is the lack of guidance provided to newcomers after asking questions. I now see that _my_ providing this guidance in the form of comments is not the right thing to do, but I think this guidance is sorely needed. I still think my initial response is unambiguous; while I can appreciate how seasoned moderators may suspect something different, again, my concern is the tone and wording of the response.

Comment: _"I still think my initial response is unambiguous"_ You're doing the same thing here, mate... Cody is **telling** you how your response is _perceived_. You may not agree, but that really doesn't matter. __Your__ response resulted in the sterner mod message. That's on you, and you alone.

Comment: @Cerbrus, it's just a disagreement on this aspect, and I'm certainly neither disputing Cody's perception and, as stated, can see how moderators in general would read this differently. So,  yes, I guess my voicing that my perception is still different wasn't necessary. Again, the main concern is the tone and wording of the response.

Comment: Which cody [explained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417570/blatantly-unprofessional-behavior-by-a-moderator-with-no-accountability?noredirect=1#comment905691_417570), and you responded to with _"I still think my initial response is unambiguous"_.

Comment: @CodyGray (I've also updated the question): It's time for me to be accountable: My first response was not as neutral as I believed it to be, so I can now see my part in this escalation.

Comment: I can sympathize a *little* bit; "*Frankly, reading your reply to this message gives the impression that you have developed quite some entitlement complex*" is inappropriate in an official response from a moderator. I would expect that from an inexperienced smaller site, perhaps, but not Stack Overflow. That being said, the moderator is correct on all the *relevant* points... and it's an unfortunate truth that responding to moderator messages is about as effective as yelling into the void (to be clear I did not read beyond your initial reply in the transcript).

Comment: Thanks, @TylerH. As hinted at in my update, I can now see my part in the escalation, due to the imperious way my asides were presented. Yet that doesn't justify the behavior that followed. As for the substance of the issue (whose discussion seemingly cannot be avoided here): I strongly disagree with characterizing accepting answers as "something that is, after all, completely optional" (in the form letter) and later "No, because the current system is more than effective enough. Accepting answers is fully optional, and not even that important." - I'll address that in a separate post.

Comment: @mklement0 Accepting *is*--and always has been--optional; this is a simple matter of fact. You can ask a question, and the system does not require that you accept an answer after one or more have been created. If it were required, you would have a time limit before the system auto-accepted the highest-scored one, or the system would allow others (moderators, trusted users, answerers... doesn't matter) to select the "accepted" answer (like Microsoft's various Q&A forums).

Comment: Whether you think it _should_ be this way is up to you, but what you think _should be_ is a separate matter from what _is_.

Comment: @TylerH, I wasn't suggesting that it is _required_ - I was thinking of framing it as "voluntary, (_if appropriate_ in a given case) but encouraged for reasons that hopefully make sense once explained". Required vs. optional (which could be read as: "do it if you feel like it") is not a helpful dichotomy. Of course what I personally think is right has no immediate bearing on anything, but that it is at odds with the status quo is not the end, but the _start_ of a future(!) discussion, to see if a potentially better shared understanding can be reached - that is what meta is for, after all.

Comment: @mklement0 couple of months back, I asked a similar [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415702/is-it-okay-to-request-a-newbie-user-to-accept-and-upvote) and I didn't get a clear answer.   Some said I requested/shared this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in at least 4% of my comments and it is not helpful.   Anyway, I no longer request/share the links.  I find some of the newbies don't know about the whole accept mechanisms and leave the post as it is.  Maybe that is what the mods wanted

Comment: Thanks, @akrun - I empathize. While I that is very much worthy of discussion, _this_  post's original intent was to focus on moderator conduct only  - please see the answer I've just added.

Comment: @CodyGray, I've elaborated on my accountability in the answer I've just added - which also refocuses this post on what it was about to begin with: moderator accountability.

Comment: Your response *does* sound like you think you’re entitled to having your answers accepted. They could have been nicer about it but I think it explains why your “fine, I’ll stop” sounds insincere.

Comment: @BSMP, it was never _just_ about me and _my_ answers, hence the _general guidance_ that my comments provided - the bigger picture here is that this guidance should be provided _automatically_. The "fine, I'll stop" came from my agreeing that it shouldn't be _I_ (or any particular user) providing this guidance. As my answer explains, I can now see why they didn't trust this declaration of intent to comply, but "could have been nicer" amounts to down-playing the blatantly personally attack that followed - just like Cerbrus' answer did.

Comment: Referenced during [the 2022 moderator election process](https://stackoverflow.com/election/14?tab=nomination#post-74366684) (near *"mod apology"*).

Answer (score -19, accepted):

Let me try to bring closure to this post:

- Its purpose - as explicitly stated in the OP - was to draw attention to improper conduct by a moderator - see the next section.
- Unfortunately, both the comments on the OP and [Cerbrus' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417573/45375) devolved into discussing the *incidental* aspect of the *subject matter* surrounding that conduct.

  - That is understandable, because it's hard to keep those two aspects separate.
  - I too got sucked back into discussing the subject matter.
  - Yet, it is a *distraction* from what this post is about.
  - Update, as an aside: said answer was later edited to include language that strikes me as *rude or abusive*, per the CoC; a flag to that effect was denied, which led to [this follow-up post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417739/45375); that post deliberately didn't mention or link back to this one, because I consider it an entirely separate issue; however, the ensuing discussion invariably involved this post, which is why I am now linking the two.
- The only thing (again) worth stating about the incidental subject matter is that *it should be discussed separately* (which I may initiate at some point *in a new post*, and which  I personally think think very much deserves discussing).

  - Update: The subject matter is now being discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418169/45375).

---

**The post was about personal conduct and accountability**.

To recap: The starting point was my receiving a warning from the moderator team not to engage in a certain behavior (again, for the purposes of *this* post, *it doesn't matter what the behavior was*, although it can certainly be gleaned from the transcript and the existing comments / answer).

**Let's start with *my* accountability:**

- *Procedural* mistakes:

  - Since my intent was never to dispute the *substance* of the warning (my intent was always to comply) I shouldn't have tried to start a *follow-up discussion* in my response - Meta is the place for that.
  - Even though I thought I had, I can now see that I did not make it sufficiently clear that *my intent was to comply*, so I was operating under the - mistaken assumption - that my first response had communicated that intent, and that my - explicitly labeled a such - *asides* were an invitation to discuss what I perceive to be the larger - impersonal - problem (again, I should have done that on Meta).
- *Etiquette* mistakes:

  - While my asides all made general points worthy of debate (and you don't have to *agree* with those points - you just need to see that they were arguments of a *general nature*, and as such *debatable*):

    - I did't want to admit to myself at the time that they were colored by my annoyance at some of what the form letter that constituted the original warning implied.
    - As a result, **the *tone* of my asides was imperious and perhaps condescending: I should not have done that**, and I can understand how that can trigger readers. I will be more mindful of how I phrase things in the future.
    - In my response to the - inappropriate and abusive - response I received (see below), I made the mistake of trying to engage the arguments at the core of the abuse, and did so in a prickly manner conducive to continuing the escalation: I should not have done that; instead, I should have limited by response to calling out the abuse (which I did at the end).

**As for *moderator* accountability**:

The premise is that I now see that my initial response didn't make it sufficiently clear that I would comply and that a response to ensure that I would was called for.

- A simple "we want to make sure that you'll abstain from the behavior we warned you about" would have sufficed.
- Optionally and ideally, a hint that *follow-up discussions* should be taken to Meta would have been appreciated.
- Instead, **the response was inappropriate and abusive**, as detailed in the OP - with no subsequent accountability.

  - While some commenters have somewhat acknowledged this, by and large it was brushed aside in favor of discussing what this post *isn't* about.
  - Indeed, we are all human and make mistakes; what matters is that we own up to them, and hopefully do better next time.
  - Moderators are in a position of power, and with power comes responsibility:

    - A big part of their job - and I applaud them for that - is dealing with frustrated users who come a them with emotions.
    - An equally big part is *not to take things personally* and *not to respond from that place*, which to me is clearly what happened here - in a particularly ugly and unaccountable fashion.

Comment: Before someone blitzes this post to derail it - the mod's answer to you was a break from the high level of professionalism SO mods had accustomed us to over the years. It lowered the bar to a level that's inexcusable and what SE the company advises in this case is using the contact form to report it as a CoC violation (because something is seriously wrong in how that went from the mod's side and it went way beyond acceptable).

Comment: Next, this latest trend of going after users like you and akrun who link to the Help Center in 4% of their comments hasn't been discussed and goes against the established long held community consensus - I could link you to posts by SO moderators who do they same in threads where they answered and there's nothing wrong with your conduct in doing so.

Comment: The historical consensus about the matter is summarized in [this post by Martjin Peters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297598) and also [this post by Bill the Lizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14999) - you did nothing wrong, because none of those guidelines have been subject to a broader debate since and thus haven't been superseded.

Comment: @bad_coder Your statements here are patently false. The actions taken by the user that led up to the moderator message were unacceptable, a clear violation of site policy, and will not be permitted going forward. I would prefer that you not give users advice that they "did nothing wrong" when following such advice is going to get them into trouble in the future. But, aside from that, as mklement has noted countless times, his intention in this Q&A is not to discuss the issue of comments about acceptance, but rather the failure/breakdown of communication on both sides w.r.t. mod messages.

Comment: @CodyGray I would have to ask you for a reference backing up your claims that invalidates Martjin Peter's and Bill the Lizard's posts (a reference that isn't just made up and was duely announced and matured with proper community feedback).

Comment: Please read Martijn's answer more carefully: "If there is a widespread pattern, flag one of posts by the user illustrating the problem, and explain the pattern in a *in need of moderator intervention* message. […] Moderators have the tools to handle cases like these. I've handled this case…" That's exactly what happened here—an *extremely* widespread pattern—and, as with the earlier case that Martijn handled, so was this one handled by moderators.

Comment: @CodyGray that's twisting the intent of what Martjin said as in the very same paragraph he validates the conduct and assumes doing so himself.

Comment: Whereas *you* are purporting to advise users regarding the permissibility of actions without having access to any knowledge regarding the context, nature, or scale at which such actions were undertaken. My claim is that that is harmful advice which will lead users astray. I am therefore requesting you to stop proffering this advice. I can assure you there is absolutely nothing being "twisted" here. It was never Martijn's intent to allow or encourage users to blast this site with hundreds or thousands of comments requesting that their own answers be accepted by askers. @bad_coder

Comment: Not only does Matjin do so himself, but I will also let him speak for himself.

Comment: @CodyGray, I appreciate your attempt to refocus the debate, as I appreciate bad_coder's perspective. Given that there's seemingly no avoiding what this post didn't want to talk about: In case your comments were meant to characterize my past conduct: that is a  gross misrepresentation of what my comments were doing: Posting comments with general advice that _an_ answer be accepted _if appropriate_, as I have,  is a very different thing from "requesting their own answers be accepted" - even if the majority (not all) of these comments were made on posts where I (also) posted answers.

Comment: @mklement0 just for the sake of disclosure and transparency I have talked to CodyGray many times before in chat so I believe I'm not mistaken to say: *"we're acquainted"* and I do consider him an *"SO friend"* although I believe he doesn't consider me as such. Now, however much I appreciate Cody he often says himself he's: *"biased; opinionated"* and his writing can make what is *his* view come across as law&decree when it's actually not. I also get a feeling he likes to -on occasion- *win arguments* but I've learned to appreciate him for his engaged approachability.

Comment: @CodyGray, additionally I think that calling for _contrition_, as you did in an earlier comment, is inappropriate, as it implies a _moral_ failing of sorts.
I am not contrite, because I acted in good faith, the aspect of self-interest notwithstanding. The short of it to me is:
My comments delivered messages _that needed delivering_. I agreed to stop, 
because I agree that it shouldn't be individual users, such as I, who deliver these messages; instead, it should be
_built into the system_. Again, this is the debate that should be conducted separately.

Comment: bad_coder, what the Martjin Peters link states is a perfect example of what I think should continue to be acceptable: if the OP goes out of their way to thank an answerer, pointing them to a help-center article about accepting answers makes perfect sense. My efforts were more methodical than that: whenever a question I was involved with - typically in the form of posting an answer, often among others - didn't result in accepting an answer, I would post a comment with general guidance. It is  this methodical approach that I believe should be automated, which eliminates concerns re self-interest

Comment: Another way of putting it: That this issue keeps coming up - users using comments to tell newcomers to do the right thing (blatant badgering aside) - is an unmistakable indication that the site itself isn't providing the necessary guidance.

Comment: No, it's an unmistakable indication that (A) users repeatedly ignore advice that they are given, and/or (B) users exercise the option *not* to accept an answer. You cannot assume that because users are not doing it that the guidance provided is insufficient. The conclusion simply doesn't follow from the premises.

Comment: @CodyGray, users can only make a choice if they know they have one. Here's a recent example of an OP leaving the following
comment on the only answer given, which they did not accept: "thank you kindly that worked perfectly, and thank you for explaining in detail its really helped my understanding cheers." Which explanation is more likely? (a) Despite those words, they made a(n undisclosed) choice not to accept. (b) They are unaware of the rules of the site.
I can assure you, this is not an isolated incident. It deserves systematic investigation, though that sounds nontrivial.

Comment: @CodyGray: We can categorize non-accepters as follows: (a) those who are unaware of the rules (b) those who know the rules, but choose not 
to accept / upvote / seek resolution via feedback (there are good and bad reasons for that, but there's nothing to be done about the bad ones). 
(c) those who know the rules,
but simply forgot to accept in a given instance (it's easy to see how that happens). Except for obvious indicators such as the
example in my previous comment, we cannot know which category applies in a given situation.

Comment: While an _automated one-time reminder_ per non-accepted question containing concise guidance would be pointless for category (b), there's a good chance categories (a) and (c) 
would be receptive to it, and category (a) - and therefore the community at large - benefits beyond just the post at hand.

Comment: The automated reminder message could offer a 1-click unsubscribe-permanently link, so as not to annoy (experienced) users who acted purposefully in not accepting.

Comment: @mklement0 just [in case you missed it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418169) turns out we were right after all and the mods issued a general apology (not that it makes up for much). This thread was plain horrible, it felt like the defense of the Alamo...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @bad_coder; indeed, this post and the loosely related [follow-up one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417739/45375) were horrible.

Comment: @mklement0 that post is an old SE trick, not to call someone names directly instead calling their post names. It is a CoC violation, the contact form has to be used (although in the past staff might have tried to also whitewash things). E.g. [Turd polishing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368606) was abolished with the VP's support, as a consequence of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368600) with [some mods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368606/could-we-talk-about-turd-polishing-better/368657#comment1229622_368607) very much in favor of verbal abuse.

Comment: @mklement0 it reflects a longstanding state of things, that abusive mods with a small fan club of users will publicly abuse people and get away with it consistently. It usually starts with one of those users most set on buttering up the mods and sucking up to the establishment consistently abusing one user in the comments with the abused user getting all their NLN flags declined. There are a few regulars that live for that kind of stuff on a daily basis. But you know what, we defended the Alamo and Cody was proven wrong all along the line; we won 1:0 that's to our credit and their discredit.

Comment: @mklement0 and once they know you don't bend and that you're not a sell out, then they get really mad. Because you're a reminder some people still have integrity and a spine to go with it.

Comment: @bad_coder Do you not see the irony in claiming that it is a CoC violation to criticize a post, yet continue—weeks later—to post side-swipes at me, by name, and imply (by comparison) that I lack integrity or a spine? I am quite offended by your comments. I have no problem whatsoever with people disagreeing with me, or even the majority of the community disagreeing with me. But for you to attack me personally in the way you've done here is really just taking it too far. Please stop.

Answer (score 42):

So, you got warned not to use comments to beg for upvotes, and then started arguing with the moderators... Of course their reply isn't going to be *perfect*, they're humans.

With great rep comes great responsibility.
Users **do** see you as an authority figure due to your big number, and as the moderator explained in those messages, vote-begging like that is just not done.

You got warned.
You argued, indicating that you were likely going to ignore the warning.
The moderator doubled down.

Seems like the system is working as intended, to me.

Could they have worded some lines better? Maybe. Does that warrant a whole meta discussion? Probably not.

Your last reply there certainly wasn't constructive. You were just throwing accusations at the moderator.

---

Seeing as this question has taken a turn of the OP doubling down on his "mods bad" train of thought, I feel I have to address part of his self-answer, that address me:

> - Its purpose - as explicitly stated in the OP - was to draw attention to improper conduct by a moderator - see the next section.
> - Unfortunately, both the comments on the OP and [Cerbrus' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417573/45375) devolved into discussing the *incidental* aspect of the *subject matter* surrounding that conduct.
>
>   - That is understandable, because it's hard to keep those two aspects separate.
>   - I too got sucked back into discussing the subject matter.
>   - Yet, it is a *distraction* from what this post is about.
> - The only thing (again) worth stating about the incidental subject matter is that *it should be discussed separately* (which I may initiate at some point *in a new post*, and which  I personally think think very much deserves discussing).

The whole issue here is that the ***OP*** started arguing with the moderator, (unintentionally) indicating he had absolutely no intention to follow the instructions.

Whilst the moderator's reply wasn't perfect, you can *hardly* hold them to a standard **you yourself** don't keep.

> After downplaying the inappropriate response, you focused on another incidental aspect: my response to it.

You keep repeating that it's "incidental". It's **not**! It's the whole reason the messages went the way they did!

That's the whole problem here.
You're trying to make the moderators look bad, and even *after* you admitted your message had a hand in the escalation:

> [image]

... you went back on your word and doubled down on your "But the mod was baaaad!" rhetoric in a self-answer here.

No, this doesn't need more analysis.
No, this doesn't need repercussions.
No, this doesn't need another question.

This pedantic over-analysis of how a mod worded what they wrote is petty, childish and a waste of everyone's time.

We get it, the message was sub-optimal. So was your first response.

All involved parties have been a bad boy. Now shake hands and get over it like adults.

Comment: Yes, my last reply was _in part_ unhelpful (my being annoyed with the response showed, unfortunately) - I should have limited my response to calling out the inappropriate behavior. Being called out for inappropriate behavior and going incommunicado is _not_ the system working, especially if the recipient is in a position of power. Posting here on meta _is_ the system working. And, not to start the discussion again, but there was no "begging" - if you read the exchange in full, perhaps my intent will become clearer (no need to follow up on this).

Comment: @mklement0 I see a very concerning pattern playing out, both in the mod message reply, as well as in the comments here: You make a bold opinionated claim, one that is almost certainly going to be objectionable and which runs directly counter to the position staked out by the other party, and then you declare that there is no need to reply or follow up on that point, essentially carving out your position as beyond refutation. That's frustrating, to say the least, if not completely disingenuous. *You* don't get to decide which of your assertions can/will be followed up on.

Comment: No, I _do_ need to follow up on that comment. Exactly as Cody said, you leave me a comment I disagree with, yet you feel the need to shut down any discussion before I get a chance to reply. I mean, _"not to start the discussion again"_ and then you immediately follow up with you starting the discussion again.., That _"vote begging"_ is just the general rule that all _"Please vote for <reason>"_ comments fall under. You're assuming I haven't read the exchange, which is extremely unconstructive. You're forgetting you're communicating with humans here. We don't all communicate perfectly.

Comment: @CodyGray, Cerbrus, I objected to the characterization as "begging", but, knowing that _this isn't what this post is about_, I only provided a brief counter-perspective. I felt we can agree to disagree on this assessment and move on. Cerbrus, I'm glad you have read the exchange - my thinking you perhaps hadn't (in full) wasn't meant to antagonize, so I apologize; I truly thought that my arguments in the exchange could shed a different light on the "begging" perspective, but seemingly not. Again: I think it's fine to simply agree to disagree here.

Comment: You failed to address _"That "vote begging" is just the general rule that all "Please vote for <reason>" comments fall under."_. They're not accusing you of begging, they're telling you to stop posting comments like that.

Comment: @Cerbrus, understood what they're asking, and my willingness to comply should be clear by now. As for begging,  I was thinking of the following statement from the second message: "Comments begging users to do things are unprofessional and unbecoming."

Comment: That was in response to your _"A perception of "begging" shouldn't be of concern to anyone"_, which is just a general statement (by you). The reply doesn't accuse you of "begging", @mklement0.

Comment: (Well, I am starting to see that my first response wasn't as neutral as I originally thought) My concern isn't  so much whether _I_ am being accused of begging, my concern was that characterizing comments that provide - in my mind - _helpful guidance_ are thought of as begging and therefore as "unprofessional and unbecoming". And this is really the crux of the problem (though this is precisely the discussion I said this post was _not_ about): Thinking that users don't need this kind of guidance, when - in my mind - they clearly do.

Comment: A __lot__ of users beg for votes, which is why we have that rule. A _lot_ of users also post comments informing others (how) to vote, in the hopes to receive upvotes, which is why more "helpful" comments also fall under that rule. I don't think any moderator thinks your information isn't _helpful_, but the comments are just not the place to do that, and that's the crux of the issue here. If you want to help new users understand the voting system, that's awesome! Comments are just not the right place.

Comment: Agreed, @Cerbrus; comments were just my personal stopgap solution that obviously had an aspect of self-interest, but were truly (also) meant to inform. This came after seeing countless OP comments to the effect of "this solved my problem" without being accompanied by accepting. To me, the right solution is for the _site itself_ to provide this kind of guidance. I'm still unclear on what the existing mechanism mentioned in the exchange is, but to me it is clear that it isn't working. Anyway, this is a subject for a separate post.

Comment: For *new* users, @mklement0 , (especially those that have never accepted an answer) then [it is acceptable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298/2029983) to let them know that instead of posting a comment that says something like "Thanks, this answered by question" the correct thing to do is the *accept* the answer. I *suspect*, however, that this is not the case here

Comment: This particular case aside, we're very much trying to discourage that, @Larnu, as far too many users are taking it as a green light to post hundreds of these comments on different posts, and that's just too much. Frankly, Ben's advice from 2014 is out of date today, with improvements to the system. It hasn't aged well, and is no longer endorsed by the moderator team.

Comment: If that's the case, @CodyGray , the linked answer should really be updated; it is not apparent that the mod team's opinion on such comments has changed (I was not aware of this and I have never been advised otherwise when I have made such comments).

Comment: @Larnu, we're now in the middle of the debate I wanted to avoid here; the post is about what I perceived as an inappropriate response, separate from the matter being debated (as I said in my update: I now see how I've contributed to an escalation). But since that genie can't be put back in the bottle: My MO was simple: for users who could be assumed to be unfamiliar with the site, I posted a comment with the broad guidance shown in the transcript. For others I posted a comment encouraging accepting or providing feedback. It is what I believe the site  should do automatically.

Comment: @CodyGray What should we do then? This entire post is a clear indicator that guiding new users to vote for good answers and accept answers which worked for them is no longer an acceptable practice, despite that it once was considered correct advice. The linked question is extremely highly up voted, as is its accepted answer, and many users of the site are still following that recommendation today. Yes, we should listen to the current recommendations by mods but the older, more popular post still muddys the water here.

Comment: In absence of clarity (not impatience, just felt this was how I as a regular user might be able to help navigate these waters) I have submitted [a new answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417578/584676) on the linked Meta question outlining that the accepted answer is now outdated, and referenced the points moderators brought up in the comments and answers of this question.

Comment: This answer's opening wording highlights an important point to me... "you were warned" -- some see mod messages as just that: messages, and others see any message as a "warning". I understand there to be a distinction (e.g. "warnings" actually *say* "this is an official warning")... if the first message were a warning, then the follow-up response might be more appropriate/warranted... but if it is just an informative message, then the situation might be different.

Comment: Perhaps the mod message needs a canned disclaimer that replies are not for arguing the finer points of the message, and such concerns should be brought to Meta or submitted to the company via the Contact Us form if necessary, instead?

Comment: @TylerH There is no distinction between "warnings" and "messages" in moderator messages. There are no templates that say "this is an official warning". As moderators, we do tend to assume that all moderator messages are a warning to knock something off. If we didn't think it rose to the level of a warning, we likely wouldn't send a moderator message, as those are retained on the official record for an account. Furthermore, the disclaimer about mod messages not being for discussion, and redirecting you to Meta and/or Contact, is there already in the sidebar.

Comment: @CodyGray Then it seems like this is a good opportunity to revise any templates the mod team uses to make it more clear that all messages are a 'knock off your <behavior> _warning_', or at least, carry a more clear 'warning' tone. The message above simply looks like a polite but firm request as written. If I were to get a mod message like that, I would certainly think "oh, this is an opportunity for me to engage in a private back-and-forth discussion or debate with a moderator directly over the points of their message", which I'm guessing is not what mods want most of the time, if ever.

Comment: @CodyGray As we both know, if something's in the side bar, it's as good as not there.

Comment: @Cerbrus, to return what this post was about to begin with, re "Could they have worded some lines better? Maybe." That's not just a _maybe_, that is _such a response should never have been posted_ and, given that it did get posted, accountability is called for - see my answer.

Comment: @TylerH, re "needs a canned disclaimer that replies are not for arguing the finer points of the message, and such concerns should be brought to Meta or submitted to the company via the Contact Us form if necessary, instead?" - hear, hear.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the feedback, @TylerH & mklement0. These perspectives are…quite honestly, something I've never once considered. It is nearly *absurd* to me that a user would receive a private message from a moderator in this format and think it was an invitation to start a discussion or some sort of friendly advice. To me, it can never be anything *but* a warning to knock it off. Replies are allowed so that extenuating circumstances can be explained and/or the policy can be clarified if necessary. But apparently my perspective is not obvious to other smart people, so room for improvement.

Comment: To summarize my concerns: You used pejorative framing to characterize the - incidental - behavior that led to the inappropriate moderator response
(arguing that said pejorative is the customary name for a group of related behaviors in a comment doesn't negate this).
You downplayed the inappropriate response as "not _perfect_",  generally suggesting that arguing against a moderator warning is in and of itself problematic, reinforced by again taking a stance on the incidental behavior.
After downplaying the inappropriate response, you focused on another 
incidental aspect: my response to it.

Comment: I thought we were past this… Why are you doubling down on this?

Comment: @CodyGray to me it's absurd the mod message was sent in the first place. mklement0 did the right thing by pointing it out there&then with a timely **wtf** instead of filling forms A-through-Z-6-to-8. We the community -mods included!- should consider ourselves lucky that only 2 users were contacted who know how to speak and stand up for themselves, it allowed to surface this issue sooner rather than later. Lastly I think a mod replying to a user with *"some sort of entitlement complex"* is snarky and unbecoming, it's the kind of thing some mods just don't do and others certainly shouldn't.

Comment: Cerbrus, on a meta (meta) note: I wasn't notified of your comment due to lack of @-addressing, so only just happened to see your comment now. My post was always about the inappropriate moderator conduct, and your answer distracted from that, by focusing on the incidental subject-matter that triggered the improper conduct, using improper framing and downplaying. That we had constructive side conversations where we reached some shared understanding is a separate issue. /cc @bad_coder

Comment: > _"You keep repeating that it's "incidental". It's not! It's the whole reason the messages went the way they did!"_

Comment: Cerbrus (again you seem to have neglected to @-address me): It _is_ incidental, and if you can't keep those two aspects separate, we should end our conversation. I'll try one more time to make the distinction clear: An inappropriate response by a moderator amounting to a personal attack is never appropriate, in and  of itself - no matter how much you or anyone agrees with the views expressed by the moderator(s) on the subject matter. As much as I empathize with how difficult it is to keep the two dimensions separate, doing so is vital, and your answer does the opposite.

Comment: You're measuring with two standards here. _Your_ inappropriate response is for some reason perfectly fine, and not to be discussed?! We've been over this already. This discussion was done. I'm not pinging you because I have no interest in investing more time in this, any more, other than refuting your repetitive "Mod bad!" claims.  You ___consistently and stubbornly___ refuse to see how ___your___ response to the mod message is at the root of all of this. Even after you admitted as much. That's hypocritical, a double standard, unconstructive, and I see no point in any more discussion.

Comment: Cerbrus: Yelling wildly inappropriate things ("Get the eff over it already") into the void doesn't make them less inappropriate. If your argument can be reduced to "You did bad things, so it's OK they did too", it is specious: Despite the - acknowledged as such by me, repeatedly - abrasive _packaging_ of my arguments, they were _debatable arguments_ (which, _incidentally_, I stand by). By contrast, the moderator response was a blatant _personal attack_. The moral equivalence you're trying to establish is all the more problematic because _moderators are in a position of power_. /cc @bad_coder.

Comment: I was typing out a whole comment about how you _are_ showing entitlement, but frankly, I've already said what I can here, multiple times. Consider that you just might be _wrong_.  It's great that there's one dude that agrees with you, but frankly, 40 upvotes on my answer, 43 downvotes on your question... How much clearer do you want it to be? Geez.

Comment: @mklement0 the previous argument (*"you got -40"*) doesn't hold much importance (what the thread did get was a 2.8 ratio, meaning 1 user in favor for less than 3 against). That's normal and pretty good for any thread asking about mod accountability (the SO mod collective usually gets it right, this is one of those rare instances when a mistake was made, so unless it's something blatant I also vote in support of mods because they put in a lot of volunteer work). E.g. [this one's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416047) net votes hide the close/reopen cycle and pressure these threads undergo.

Comment: @mklement0 The usual pattern of pressuring the OP into submission (thereby supression) has been broken in this thread. [Verbal abuse was in the order of the day during the last election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/13) - with one candidate being accused of it and another candidate making the campaing promess to address it. What we saw in this thread are the conditions that mislead mods into partaking or overlooking verbal abuse (personal attacks are CoC violations).

Comment: Hear, hear, @bad_coder, and thanks for the background. Cerbrus: We've arrived at the heart of the matter: You seem to think that
a perception of entitlement justifies ad hominem arguments and verbal abuse by moderators. (Your previous comment - "Get the eff over it already"- shows that you're no stranger to personally engaging in abuse either). That so many others agree with you is unfortunate - sometimes there's weakness in numbers. It isn't the job of a moderator to critique and berate perceived personality traits. If and when personal attacks occur, there needs to be accountability.

Comment: And yet again you maliciously misinterpret my intentions. I really have nothing more to add. I’m not repeating myself any longer.

Comment: @Cerbrus Please stop. No one is being intentionally malicious here; those words are pouring unnecessary gasoline onto this thread. Your focus is squarely on OP taking accountability for their arguing. OP's focus is on the mod's words when "doubling down", which were arguably much more attacking than they needed to be. Neither side was perfectly eloquent, both have things to learn and takeaway from this experience. I think the back and forth can be done at this point.

Comment: @zcoop98 I'm free to defend myself here. I'm being portrayed as the "bad guy" in the OP's answer and comments. I won't stand for that.

Comment: @Cerbrus My point is that accusations of the other party being "malicious" don't help your case. No more, no les..

Comment: And those accusations being addressed at me are equally pointless.

Answer (score -27):

The site, in form of moderators, dictate the rules and you need to comply or leave the site.

You agreed to the rules and should so follow them and should not try to bend them a little, especially when you get warned, presumably more than once.

A dispute will not bear any fruits as the case will be discussed beforehand and then you get the message, which is more a last straw for you.

Comment: Your answer exhibits the very kind of intransigence and speculation based on  bad-faith assumptions ("presumably more than once") I was trying to call out in my question. No one was trying to "bend them [the rules] a little". My response indicated my willingness to stop, and wanted to start a conversation about how to improve the site (which was probably misplaced, but that's a separate matter)

Comment: The problem comes when there are well-received community discussions that juxtapose the current position(s) of the mod team. The waters muddy considerably more when you consider that mklement0's behavior was once the recommended and mod-team-endorsed behavior on the site. So while maybe engaging in discourse about the issue within modmail may have been the wrong place to do it, it's not like there were no grounds for refutation considering the history of this particular rule.

Comment: It is not true that this was previously the moderator team's endorsed behavior... The author of that Meta post was never a moderator.

Comment: @CodyGray You literally said [the opposite](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417570/blatantly-unprofessional-behavior-by-a-moderator-with-no-accountability#comment905718_417573) yesterday. Maybe it wasn't endorsed and you misspoke, but clearly there is a disconnect between the moderators position and what was previously considered acceptable behavior. No, OP shouldn't have used the mod message to argue their case, but it's unfortunate the mod team doesn't understand why the mod teams reaction to the initial comments is surprising to several community members.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I think Cody meant that Ben's answer has never been or should have been used as an indicator of what the mod team endorses and rather used to be what community at large considers to be an acceptable caveat.

Comment: *"The site, in form of moderators, dictate the rules and you need to comply or leave the site."* - no they enforce the rules, the site owners dictate them (or did so a long time ago, anyway). But since this is a community driven site, we all enforce the rules. Some just enforce a few more.

Comment: What Oleg said, @Bender. My initial comment was not meant to imply that the mod team previously endorsed this policy, only that it got highly voted on Meta because users thought it was a good idea, and it at least did have some justification that could be offered in its favor way back in 2014. Aside from that, what the mod team finds surprising is how an answer that says "It's okay…once" can be taken to justify a user posting *hundreds* if not *thousands* of such comments over the span of a couple of years. That's unreasonable noise. So far, these are the only cases where we've sent warnings.

Comment: @CodyGray, since we're in the weeds: my behavior, which did span years, was completely unrelated to any Meta discussions: I rarely participate on Meta, and on the few occasions I have, I have found it to be a toxic place - this case being no exception. I acted on what made sense to me: compensating for what I perceive to be glaring lack of guidance provided to new users by the site itself; and it's becoming increasingly clear to me that I am not alone in this assessment. But, let's not forget: this isn't what this post is about.

Comment: So…@mklement0, I appreciate your perspective to some extent, and I think there may have been some good come out of this discussion (see, e.g., [this comment](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417570/#comment906089_417573)). I want to say, personally, that I am sorry for how the message(s) resonated with you and that you were offended by the tone and/or presentation. That was not anyone's intention, I can assure you. Part of the reason I think this Meta discussion got derailed is because you came out swinging against mods, and not only us mods but some members of the community get defensive about that

Comment: We are all humans, we do get frustrated (even though we probably shouldn't), we do misjudge situations (sometimes out of pure ignorance, other times out of being rushed, other times because of unrelated personal issues, or any other of dozens of reasons). So we're certainly not above criticism. On the other hand, your post implied that we have no accountability (which isn't true) and it made some pretty sweeping assertions, of the same kind that you responded negatively to yourself when they were made about/to you. Of course, you've learned something, too, so all good in the end.

Comment: @CodyGray, I truly appreciate the constructive engagement. As for users being naïve about moderator messages: I certainly am, despite having been around for a long time, so TylerH's suggestion about focused canned follow-up messages makes perfect sense to me. And, poignantly,
his point about "if something's in the side bar, it's as good as not there", applies to the subject matter of the debate here: New users aren't _actively guided_ to the behavior that benefits the community at large.

Comment: @CodyGray, while I can appreciate the sentiment behind "I am sorry for how the message(s) resonated with you", it
doesn't acknowledge that the _second_ message - not the original form letter - was a blatantly cantankerous and personal attack.
I have taken responsibility for potentially having _triggered_ such a response with the abrasive _packaging_ of my arguments, but  that doesn't _excuse_ the response.
So, in this particular case, I see no accountability.

Comment: I meant the second message, not the first one. There's nothing whatsoever in the first one that could possibly be apologized for. The frustration at feeling like our message was not being received (and, in fact, was being contested) that came out in the second one is what I meant to apologize for. I continue to see nothing of the sort which you have continually claimed in the second message (unprofessional, personal attack, etc.), although I am willing to allow for the fact that it was framed in such a way that made you feel attacked, and that is what I meant to apologize for. @mklement0

Comment: I appreciate it, @CodyGray, and I agree that the _first_ message has nothing to apologize for (it has problematic aspects, which my responses tried to address, but these problematic aspects have nothing to do with improper conduct). As for the assessment of the _second_ message: I am personally baffled that you don't see what I see, but I accept that this is your perspective (and I appreciate that you're sorry for the effect on me); I will let the quotes in the OP (and the transcript)  speak for themselves.

Comment: @CodyGray this is some serious gaslighting Cody, claiming the thread got derailed by fault of the OP, the message wasn't offensive... What's happening is that you're decreeing a rule against historical (and network-wide) consensus without making an announcement to let the community know about it (I'd love to see the reactions). There is no accountability for mods (that's long been a well known fact). But I think you're missing something here, it's that [the CMs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341) wouldn't agree with you, but you know the community wouldn't so you hide the announcement.

Comment: @mklement0 I'm gonna give my personal verdict here and call the issue closed: I can guess who the mod is that contacted you and he's a soft-spoken, gentle, considerate, friendly, *"they don't get no better"* kind of guy. In 3 years of participating on SO I've seen him be discourteous exactly twice (and that was recently) so it's *once in a blue moon*. Why am I saying this? Because I've had the pleasure of chatting with these folks on a colloquial level and I don't think the mod that messaged is doing himself -or you- justice. This whole thing comes across as so uncharacteristic it's unreal...

Comment: @mklement0 now regarding the whole issue of starting to strictly prohibit the "accept" comments it should be vetted by the community. The rational in the mod message is overlooking so many relevant aspects I can't believe it wasn't sanity-checked better. I think whoever agreed to this in the mod backroom is making a mistake and I'm left wondering just how many mods agreed with it and if they're aware of the change in enforcement.

Comment: Re the inappropriate response, @bad_coder: Thanks, I appreciate the background information. Seemingly, my initial response struck a personal nerve. I've taken responsibility for my (comparatively small, in my estimation) part in this; I hope he does for his, at least privately, so it won't happen again. I agree that even the canned message reveals a problematic stance toward the issue, with two worrisome manifestations: (a) faulting users for violating a dogmatic, seemingly never announced as such rule, and (b), showing indifference toward guiding new users toward productive behavior.