# Does calling another user's behavior "petty, childish, and a waste of everyone's time" in an answer not qualify as rude or abusive?

Tags: discussion, moderation, rude-or-abusive

Said phrase is used in an answer to a question that - ironically - is about verbal abuse.

When I flagged the answer first, the flag was deemed helpful, and I got this response:

> I had already spoken to the offender. I marked this flag as helpful, but.. you could have just flagged the comment and edited out the sentence, and let it all simmer down.

The comment being referenced refers to an abusive comment that *was* removed by the moderators, but the offending sentence in the answer was not.

I responded with:

> The offensive sentence is still in the answer ("petty, childish"). If *I* were to edit it out, it would be the opposite of letting things simmer down - it would lead to escalation. Hence, I ask again that *you* do that.

This time, the flag was declined - and the offending sentence remains in the answer; the response was:

> The user is entitled to express their opinion your behavior is "petty, childish and a waste of everyone's time". You're welcome to disagree with that and express it by downvoting. No mod action needed

I find this baffling, because to me the sentence is clearly rude and abusive.

Also, it sounds like there's disagreement among the seemingly two different moderators that handled the flag, given that the first
response seems to imply agreement that the sentence is rude - though I do find it strange that it was suggested for *me* to edit out the sentence.

Comment: Do you take offence with *how* they said it or *that* they said it?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: It's about _how_. Obviously, expressing the idea that "this isn't worth discussing" is and of itself not problematic.

Comment: Saying _"Your behavior is petty and childish"_ is no different from saying _"You are petty and childish"_. I think that trying to demarcate a difference between one and the other, and saying one is a personal attack and the other not, is simply wrong. Or maybe it's simply pettiness and childishness. I don't know.

Comment: @yivi, agreed - but did you mean to post your comment below Cody's answer?

Comment: @yivi The actual quote is "This pedantic over-analysis of how a mod worded what they wrote is petty, childish and a waste of everyone's time." Nowhere does it say that the usual behaviour or even the person is petty and childish.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Is that supposed to be less rude? I find it even worse. I may be getting oversensitive with age.

Comment: @yivi It's supposed to clear up the facts, since they seem to be conveniently swept under the rug. "This behaviour", "Your behaviour" and "You" certainly aren't the same thing in my book.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, nothing is being swept under the rug: note that the title of this post reads "Does calling another user's _behavior_ ..."

Comment: @mklement0 Which is already a stretch. They didn't call out your general behaviour out of the blue. They did call out the behaviour being explicitly discussed.

Comment: Sorry, @MisterMiyagi. Why do you think I "conveniently" did anything? You mean I intentionally worded things in a way that intended to support my argument while actually misconstruing facts? I apologize, that was not my intention. I was just trying to be brief, and I think that the point stands. I still believe the original quote is rude. Using "this behavior" as a smokescreen for "you" does not do anything for me. But I don't think we are going to agree, and that the whole thing is rather pointless. Either one feels the quote is rude, or doesn't. Moving on. Bye.

Comment: @yivi I was not intending to imply you left out things. That the way the question is worded led you to assume the initial quote used a wording it did not kind of underlines my issue, though.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, this isn't about adjudicating whether the rude statement is _justified in light of what prompted it_, it is about a statement that is and of itself rude. It needs no further context. If you don't see it as rude, we can agree to disagree. For the purpose of this post, nothing is missing or omitted. If you think that quoting the full sentence makes a difference: you now have done so, so that concern should be resolved.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, as for yivi's concern: their opinion is that there's no substantive difference between "your behavior is X" and "you are X", so it doesn't matter how they read the question (which only talks about behavior). By contrast, it is Cody's answer that explicitly makes this distinction, which is why I thought yivi's comment should have been posted there.

Comment: What exactly is the goal here?

Comment: "petty" and "waste of everyone's time" are probably fine, but "childish" is borderline. Depends on the context I would say.

Comment: @TylerH, I'd say that insults are insults, irrespective of context. In context, you may sympathize with what triggered them, but to me that doesn't justify them.
No matter what the behavior being criticized is, there is a respectful, non-insulting way to express the criticism - and it's much more likely to be heard.

Comment: The respectful criticism clearly __wasn't heard__, though. It was ignored, and disregarded / discredited as a _"distraction"_ from what you wanted to discuss. At that point you honestly can't be surprised people start using stronger language.

Comment: @Cerbrus, your criticism was _heard_ but _disagreed with_. If a post asks you not discuss X, and you discuss X, that is the very definition of a distraction. You may feel that X still _should_ be discussed, and I told you why I think it shouldn't, and why the moral equivalence you tried to establish ("both sides did bad things") was specious. You can argue against these points, or you can exit the conversation. Nothing entitles you to your perspective being _validated_, and nothing entitles you to resort to insults.

Comment: And likewise you _could_ refrain from repeating the same old story over and over again of how you think my answer was a "distraction". This is ___exactly___ what I mean. The criticism is dismissed because you consider it irrelevant, but that criticism is at the ___very core___ of the whole issue.

Comment: @Cerbrus, perhaps the previous comment didn't make it sufficiently clear: Nothing entitles you to your perspective being validated, and nothing entitles you to resort to insults.

Comment: And nothing entitles you to shut down other user's answers, just because you disagree with their content or relevance. I'm not looking for validation. I'm looking for you to _accept_ that SO just doesn't hold to the same standards as you do, yourself. That much is abundantly clear from the votes on both questions.

Comment: @Cerbrus, _arguing_ why an answer isn't relevant is completely different from _shutting it down_ - a power I clearly neither possess, nor is it my intent: to me, arguments are always an invitation to a dialog - which either side is free to exit any time - and which ideally leads to a shared understanding, or at least to a - respectful - agreement to disagree.

Comment: You dismiss my answer as "distracting", post your own with your own interpretation that's literally opposite to what's accepted, and finally accept your own answer... You can't _literally_ shut my answer down, but you're making it abundantly clear you think my answer shouldn't even be there. Note that I ___had___ exited this whole debacle. Then you wrote that little gem of an answer. You can't expect anyone not to respond when you're literally writing about them.

Comment: @Cerbrus, it's entirely your choice to interpret a - non-offensive, non-personal - _argument_ as to why your answer is a distraction as "dismissing it"; that has nothing to do with me. It's your choice to get offended that I posted my own answer and accepted it; that has nothing to do with me. What _does_ have to do with me is if you let these personal choices erupt into insults.

Comment: Please take a note from your own writing: _"As a result, the tone of my asides was imperious and perhaps condescending: I should not have done that, and I can understand how that can trigger readers. I will be more mindful of how I phrase things in the future."_ You are being condescending right now. _"It's your choice to get offended"_ _"that has nothing to do with me"_... Don't you see the hypocrisy here? ___I___ should "choose" not to be offended, but _your_ offense can not be  questioned? Come on!

Comment: @Cerbrus, I think we've finally reached common ground: come on! And, with this, I make a solemn to promise to exit this conversation. It's easy. No insults required.

Comment: Dude, I’ve been at “come on!” since my “get the hell over it already” comment, already...

Comment: Yet again you've accepted your own, heavily downvoted answer over an answer the community voted for, written by a moderator (who you'd think knows what he's talking about). To me, this looks like you're not interested in what the community thinks, you just want people to agree with you. There's a closure reason for that...

Comment: it is hard tu guess what the cause is, calling some one childish, isn't rude nor abusive, it is a respond to some ones behaviour prior, as we don't know what it is, so how should we guess what happens

Comment: @nbk: Why are you wasting my time with this petty, childish response?
I hope you recognize this for the satire it is. Now that I assume you feel wronged,
does it not feel like an insult to you? Conversely, is it justified when you just
so happen to agree with the insult? Clearly, whether it is "justified" is in the eye of the beholder, 
and an insult doesn't just magically disappear if you sympathize with it.
As detailed in my answer, the actual _message_ buried deep inside this insult can be expressed in a non-offensive manner, and that is what I wish we all strived for.

Comment: @mklement0 calling a behauviour childish, is not abusive, it only means that i think that you have reached maturity for the case, which has nothing to do ith your actual age, so you didn't post the link to the question, and that is why we downvote your question and closed your question.

Answer (score -20, accepted):

I want to address several aspects I perceive to be problematic in [Cody Gray's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417740/45375), and doing so wouldn't fit into comments:

> This is in the context of the rude stuff you said about moderators in that other Meta question you posted, right? The irony is strong with this one.

It is ironic, but not for the reasons you think: the post in whose context the offending statement was made was a *complaint about* rudeness (by a moderator, which heightens the irony).

If you think there is something rude about the complaint itself, you should take action - just like I tried to with the offending statement.

The bigger picture, here, however, is:

One act of rudeness doesn't justify another, no matter how much you sympathize with the stance that the rudeness is in support of.

We need no further context to discuss the offending statement: it is offensive in and of itself (in my estimation, needless to say).

It is also baffling that you link to a post about the word "pedantic".
While certainly not friendly and debatable in terms of its offensiveness, it isn't the issue, which is why I didn't include it in what I quoted in my question.
But, for the record, here's the full sentence:

> This pedantic over-analysis of how a mod worded what they wrote is petty, childish and a waste of everyone's time.

It certainly isn't expressing *an opinion* that is problematic, it is expressing an *insulting* opinion.

Every insult is an opinion, but that doesn't justify it.

Distilling your logic to its essence, I hear:

A statement that talks about *behavior* rather than a *person* cannot be insulting.

Let's start with the following opinion:

> Get the eff over it already. Geez.

In essence, this opinion (or behavioral recommendation) expresses the same sentiment as the offending statement.
In non-offensive terms (which could have been used, and would have been perfectly acceptable): "You are making too much of this. It is not productive to talk about this."

Yet, at least *one* moderator agreed that this was offensive and removed this comment, which was made on the same answer that
contains the offending statement.

While not as vulgar, the offending statement is similarly dismissive and insulting - even if it isn't *directly* ad hominem.

This fallacy - an opinion can't be offensive if it doesn't directly address a person -
in effect gives users permission to insult freely, as long as they say, "you did something that a $!@# would do" instead of "you are a $!@#"

I think that your stance therefore does a disservice to the community, which is especially problematic because you're a moderator.

And I hope it is clear that in this case I truly am addressing your behavior, based on arguments, not insults.

Comment: No offense but I struggle to see what you're trying to accomplish here. Looking at the scores of your posts should already tell you that meta is of the opinion that your indignation is unwarranted. Further arguing that the behaviour was indeed rude feels pretty pointless because besides yourself nobody really cares. Seems to me like you've found yourself in a hole and decided that the best course of action is to start digging...

Comment: @l4mpi: I am trying to raise awareness that rudeness is being tolerated on this site, which isn't just a personal issue.
Don't you think that's important? If you don't see it, you can either dispute specific points I've made to
help me understand why I shouldn't see it that way either, or, if you don't want to expend the energy, you can simply move on
and let the votes speak for themselves (which, in my estimation and experience, they don't on Meta).

Comment: Nope, I don't think that's important. You're complaining about language that would be acceptable in a middle school (if not earlier). We're all adults here and adults have disagreements, and requiring those to be expressed in a 100% politically correct way that's as inoffensive as humanly possible would be way worse for open and honest discussion. As long as there are actual arguments, and the discussion doesn't devolve into pure name calling, I think it's fair game. Then again, I would love if we had a "GTFO and RTFM" close reason on main, so my opinion might not be representative.

Comment: @l4mpi, if we're all adults here, then we shouldn't talk like middle schoolers. When we occasionally slip up and do, we should own up to it.

Comment: I'm an adult and thus I talk however the hell I want, thanks. Of course I "own up" by accepting consequences for my speech... which as you've seen are nonexistent for calling someone's behaviour "childish" on meta. Not sure why you think that adults shouldn't use these words - the middle school comment was intended to demonstrate that the words used were already "kid-friendly". If you want to ban that kind of language, then what's left? I'd have to consult a laywer and ethics comittee before writing my opinions about some of the more ridiculous things SO (the company) decides to do.

Comment: @l4mpi, if you're talking however the hell you want, as you put it, then there's no point in discussing what's acceptable to say. To me, it's not about the _degree_ of rudeness, but about avoiding it altogether, and I don't think that is hard to do, by reflecting on, as a response is being formulated, whether it is colored by anger and whether the _packaging_ of the argument (assuming there is one) is likely to antagonize instead of furthering a shared understanding or at least having a respectful disagreement.

Comment: Avoiding it alltogether? That's literally impossible as "rudeness" is not an objectively measurable quantity but is subjective, and my perception of what is and isn't rude is not shared by all of humanity. For example, some people might get offended by the word "petty", while others consider it to be perfectly acceptable. As another example, some people might consider beating dead horses to be rude, so if you don't want to offend them you might have to stop posting...

Comment: @l4mpi, it's something to be aspired to (my previous comment suggests how); while, there is no objective standard, there's a widely shared understanding, at least in a given culture / language.
The dead-horse angle does not apply to a conversation with entirely voluntary participation. But, by your logic, beating dead horses should be perfectly acceptable, as long as someone doesn't find it rude.

Comment: The "widely shared understanding" in the meta SO culture seems to be that you're in the wrong though. But don't let that stop you from beating this dead horse...

Comment: My impression is not that this is raising awareness of rudeness, but spreading rudeness. The meta from which this thing spawned is heavy with one-sided accusations and allegation. Now this meta picks up on *one* sentence from a page-long reply that may be seen as rude, mixes it with filtered mod reactions, and spins it up again in a similar manner...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I strongly disagree with this characterization, and I'll let this and the original post speak for itself (especially in view of my own answer there). Embedding an insult in a longer post also doesn't justify it, and the two posts are only incidentally connected, which is why I didn't link to the earlier one: This one is purely about something that I perceive to be clearly offensive being allowed to stand after having flagged it, and now, after Cody's answer, how I view a moderator's stance on this as fundamentally problematic.

Comment: I really don't see how you can claim context should be ignored. Flagging happens on an *answer*, because flagging a sentence is not possible, so purely from a standpoint of complaining about the procedure it matters. Meaning of words depends on context, so purely from a standpoint of asking whether it is rude or abusive it matters. Both your question and answer keep on alluding to the context, so...

Comment: 1- Please be aware of the context of the offending sentence. (Which I am uniquely qualified to provide, being the author of said words): That other meta question _already_ came to a conclusion, namely, "everyone sucked here". mklement admitted he had a hand in the escalation, and as far as I could tell, it was __over__. Then, some ~2 days later, the discussion get restarted with a answer calling out my answer as a "distraction", and a whole lot of "meta sucks"-kind of rambling. _That_ is the point at which I expanded my existing answer, including the quoted line.

Comment: 2-  I felt it was necessary to defend my answer, because of the poor attitude displayed in both the OP's question _and_ answer. TL;DR: If people can't kiss and make up after a fight, I'm inclined to call it out.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, it wasn't I who started alluding to the context, it was Cody, and my answer tries its best to keep it out of this discussion. As I've argued before, the offending sentence is in and of itself offensive, irrespective of its context. Dragging context into this only creates a distraction (just like discussing the subject matter of the warning rather than the moderator behavior was in the original post). And, of course flagging requires flagging the whole answer; I didn't use the "rude or abusive" flag, I used a custom flag so I could highlight the offensive part.

Comment: @mklement0 "it wasn't I who started alluding to the context" The very first sentence of this question alludes to the context: "Said phrase is used in an answer to a question that - ironically - is about verbal abuse."

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, fair enough, but that was an abstract reference, as an aside; it was _not_ meant to drag the other post into this discussion, and therefore I neither linked to it nor, perhaps more importantly, discussed its contents; it merely pointed out the irony of a complaint about abuse suffering abuse too (in my estimation).

Comment: See, it's this kind of one-sided interpretation that irks me. You reserve the right to interpret your own words with leniency, yet harshly interpret those of others. You reserve the right to decide which words are worth discussing and which are merely distraction. Please take a step back to consider how this appears if one does not start at agreeing with your interpretation already: Things are being heavily re-framed here to enforce a selective narrative that only supports your opinion. If you really "realize [you] must show accountability [yourself]", please start doing so.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I've done so, extensively, in [my own answer to my previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417618/45375) (there we go), and I see no leniency in how I describe my actions there. The larger point still stands: I posted a needlessly prickly response - which wasn't personal, however, and made specific arguments - and the response was a personal attack, by a moderator, who is in a position of power, and arguably should be held to a higher standard. There is no reframing here, only a (to me) obviously offensive statement that needs no context to be recognized as such.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, another way of putting it: to me, the offending sentence is unacceptable per se, in any context; if there's a momentary lapse in judgment due to mounting frustration, which we can all relate to, there needs to be accountability.

Comment: @Cerbrus: You seem to think that frustration entitles you to verbal abuse. The frustration seems to have come from an imagined fight you were a part of - there
was no fight to begin with, and thus no reason to make peace. I came back to refocus the conversation on what my question was about, which your answer had derailed and downplayed. I've also argued why the moral equivalence you were trying to establish ("both sides did bad things") is specious. You needn't agree, you only need to recognize that these were non-offensive arguments. Your characterization of my actions is abrasive.

Comment: @Cerbrus: In short: You've justified verbal abuse twice: first a moderator's, then your own. In the former case, I have extensively owned up to my part in having triggered the personal attack (through needlessly prickly, but impersonal arguments), _but that still doesn't make the verbal abuse that followed OK_, especially not from a moderator. In the latter case, I have nothing to own up to.

Comment: _"Your characterization of my actions is abrasive."_ Soooo, how is it okay to say that, but _"This <...> is petty, childish and a waste of everyone's time."_ isn't okay? Again, you're applying a double standard here.

Comment: I may have missed something in the other Meta, but when was it established that the moderator did verbally abuse someone? Because this gets repeated here again and again as if it were a fact...

Comment: @Cerbrus, it is my description of _and a whole lot of "meta sucks"-kind of rambling_. It is another (milder) example of verbal abuse, and, obviously, _some_ language must be used to describe it. How about inappropriate?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi [See for yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417570). We came to the conclusion that the moderator could've (/should've) worded it better, but that it was warranted.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, you just need to read the quotes [in the original post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417570/45375), and can refer to the linked transcript for the full picture. Of course, what constitutes verbal abuse is debatable; to me, it is blatantly obvious, but I invite everyone to see for themselves.

Comment: Lol, what? How is calling this rambling "rambling" __abuse__? That's akin to calling "rape!" when someone looks at you funny.

Comment: @mklement0 I read the cherry picked quotes *as well as their actual context*, guess why I am not willing to take out-of-context claims at face value...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, personal attacks don't need context to condemn; they are unacceptable in and of themselves. Sympathizing with the impulse to indulge in them in a given context  doesn't make them acceptable. Thinking I didn't present the full picture doesn't make them acceptable (the full context was available from the start; of course my post represented _my_ perspective). That they came from a moderator is doubly unacceptable.

Comment: context may not always be necessary to determine what is and isn't acceptable, *it is however extremely necessary to determine what the resulting actions should be.* What actions are you asking for here? To apply a label to something?

Comment: I can't honestly think of any good reason why you'd want to _hide_ the context of the behaviour you're discussing... The only reason I could think of would be that the context might weaken your argument...

Comment: @Cerbrus: No one is _hiding_ context: Here, the context is a declined flag on what to me is an obviously offensive statement; no more context needed.
In the original post, the context was all there, and, despite my efforts to keep the post focused on the personal attack, the discussion 
focused on the context instead, which led to you _justifying_ the attack instead of acknowledging it as such, just like you justified your own offensive statement. As stated, what I needed to own up to myself I have done extensively - it involved abrasively packaged arguments, not personal attacks.

Comment: @KevinB, first I was hoping to find consensus that the offending statement comes under the heading "rude or abusive" - if there is no such consensus, there isn't much point in talking about what should be done. But, to indulge the hypothetical: I expected the moderator to remove the statement and tell the OP to replace it with a non-offensive statement, if desired, along the lines of "You are making too much of this. It is not productive to talk about this."  (Note how the original mod suggested that I personally remove the statement, which I don't think would be appropriate.)

Comment: @mklement0 You are again jumping ahead – that these things *are* personal attacks and context would merely be sought to rate, possibly reject, their *severity*. That the only open question is how to *condemn* them. There is nothing "of course" about presenting *your* perspective, one that frankly seems frighteningly toxic and hostile, when it comes alongside the claim that the "of course" for others' perspective – i.e. *context* – is not worth any consideration.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, if calling out a personal attack and showing exasperation in doing so is "frighteningly toxic and hostile", I'll own that. That I _initially_ didn't see my own part in this is unfortunate, but I certainly hope that my answer made up for it (now even linked to from the question). My post _argues_ why the mod response was a personal attack. Of course, you don't have to agree. All the information is there for everyone to judge.

Comment: @mklement0 You just did it again... reframe it as *being* a personal attack, and me just putting a label on that...

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, if I may quote myself: "My post _argues_ why the mod response was a personal attack. Of course, you don't have to agree."

Comment: If you would only *argue* that, I wouldn't have a problem. That many of your statements are framed as if what you argue is already established as fact, that is something I absolutely do not agree with.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, and I do not agree with your framing of my posts (by _many_ you mean my last two questions and my own answers to them, I presume). It goes without saying that posts about perceived abusive behavior are invariably subjective - and therefore doesn't strictly need saying. And, revisiting this question's wording, I believe it actually _does_ say it: "because to me the sentence is clearly rude and abusive."

Comment: @mklement0 I mean your [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417618/5349916) and comments which continue to casually claim the moderator was indeed verbally abusive. I mean quibs that there is irony in the flagged phrase being in a context about verbal abuse, which only makes sense if it *is* abuse itself. I mean this answer framing the initial Q&A as a "complaint about rudeness", but a reply to it as a reaction to "*(perceived)* rudeness". I mean comments that already take for granted that "rudeness is being tolerated on this site". I mean comments that "the larger point still stands"..

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, yes, because all of that is still my perception, supported by arguments you may or may not agree with. The irony comment makes sense whether or not there was actual abuse (which comes down to _consensus_). Fair enough about the one-sided "(perceived)" - I've removed it. And, indeed, emphatically, _to me_ the larger point still stands.

Comment: I kind of wonder what you were hoping to achieve with this meta post at this point though. Your meta post is pretty decently downvoted, your own meta answer has but a single upvote and 17 downvotes and Cody Gray's answer is pretty decently upvoted. The statistics don't lie, your opinion is not in alignment with that of your peers. So... now what? What's the next step? Use this as proof to yourself that Stack Overflow is dead because "everyone" else is wrong (meta of course does not represent the entire user base)... or do you try to find a way to align yourself better with others?

Comment: @Gimby, I naively thought that this _question_ would be uncontroversial, given how obvious it was to me
that we're dealing with an insult. 
Clearly, many beg to differ. 
I posted my _answer_, because I think Cody's logic is flawed and encourages similar (what I would consider) verbal abuses in the future.
Truth is not a numbers game, and a community's culture can change; my - perhaps futile - hope is that my posts contribute toward
a change for the (in my estimation) better.
And, to be clear: it's not Stack Overflow, it is *Meta* SO that I find myself out of alignment with.

Comment: @Gimby, if you're up for a little social experiment: show this post to non-peers in your life, and see what they think of it with respect to insults vs. respectful criticism.  Then show it to peers who _aren't_ active on Meta SO.
Sure, a given community can decide on its own culture that need not be aligned with that of the culture at large, but - if I were to guess - even among our peers you'll find many that are out of alignment with Meta SO; they may just not be around any longer or they may stay silent.

Comment: @Gimby, there are those who hang out here for fun, as regular contributors, and those that come here with specific needs only.
I fall into the latter category, and, based on my past experience, by and large it feels like a hostile place to me, so I have stayed away.
And that would be fine, if it weren't for pressing needs arising from time to time that _necessitate_ coming here, meaning that the site isn't just for the regulars.
And it is then that I, and presumably others, hope for _respectful_ discussions, which is the case this post is making.

Comment: @mklement0 What... words would describe the sentiment and not be "verbal abuse" as you see it? Would it instead have needed to be a demand, such as "Stop wasting everyone's time."?

Comment: @KevinB, an example is in this answer (also repeated in an earlier comment). Arguably, the core sentiment had already been expressed in _non-offensive terms_ in the very same answer, before the offending sentence was added: "Could they have worded some lines better? Maybe. Does that warrant a whole meta discussion? Probably not." While I clearly don't agree with this assessment, I certainly feel it's a valid, non-offensively formulated opinion.

Comment: @KevinB, as for "Stop wasting everyone's time": that is a pure expression of anger, and to me equally unacceptable. Taken at face value: no one can speak for everyone, and the concept
of wasting anyone's time clearly doesn't apply to a debate with entirely voluntary participation. Anyone is free to walk away at any time.

Comment: I mean, that's clearly not the case, given a large portion of our policies here revolve around not wasting the time of the limited people who actually perform review tasks, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @KevinB, if that were truly the concern, vote to close, and move on. If you additionally want to take the time to provide guidance, especially to someone whom you perceive to be creating unproductive posts repeatedly, say something like: "This strikes me as a trivial concern. Please consider that even just reading your post and voting to close takes time that could be spent better elsewhere."
Saying "stop wasting everyone's time" after voluntarily having created a lengthy answer and numerous comments is absurd. You can just walk away or say that you're exiting the discussion.

Comment: @mklement0 You can just walk away or say that you're exiting the discussion.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, indeed I can. Clearly, I'm choosing of my own free will to continue to respond to comments here, as do you - always an opportunity to learn. May I ask why are you telling me this?

Comment: @mklement0 Because I do think you would do well to follow your own advice. Not just the "walk away" part, mind.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I didn't advise anyone to walk way per se. I said that, after a lengthy discussion that someone voluntarily participated in, to say "stop wasting everyone's time" is absurd, and that the better, non-inflammatory option is to walk away. What other part do you have in mind?

Comment: If that's what you took from my comment, it's not what i meant. Rather, it's part of the quote you seem to be calling abusive, that I requested you assist in determining an alternative. If there can't be an alternative, and any attempt at informing you of the... problems your comments asking people to accept answers cause is "abusive"... i'm not sure we have any common ground on what "abusive" means.

Comment: Understood re submitting too quickly, @KevinB. As for the alternative: There is the one I previously pointed you too, that is part of the answer, but I'm happy to quote it again: "You are making too much of this. It is not productive to talk about this." There's also my comment that the answer already had a non-offensive formulation of essentially the same sentiment. What the moderator warning that prompted the previous post was about is completely incidental not just to this discussion, but also to the previous post.

Comment: @mklement0 The thing about not being rude and abusive just because one is frustrated comes to mind. Reflecting on whether things are likely to be antagonizing before saying them, and generally going back to revise offensive language where possible.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, no disagreement there: what things that I said strike you as offensive and should therefore be revised? Except for the exasperation reflected in my previous post (the question part, not the answer), nothing comes to mind. Are you thinking of "blatantly unprofessional"? I'm happy to tone that down, to, say, "personal attack" - which I truly believe it was.

Comment: @mklement0 "Blatantly unprofessional behavior", "unwarranted assumptions of ill intent", "unwarranted speculation about motivation", "casting aspersions", "a patronizing attitude", "gratuitous threats", "no accountability", "the response was inappropriate and abusive", …. Yes, even the "personal attack" unless you make it clear that is how it *appeared to you* instead of implying or outright saying that's what it is.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, fair enough, I've made some of those changes, along with a preamble explaining the changes. Some of the phrases I stand by, but I'm open to discussing them further.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, understood that you don't want to show up in the previous post, but please know that it was meant to give you credit for inspiring me to make the post less incendiary.

Comment: @mklement0 I'm sure Cerbrus and the unnamed mod could make a similar statement of meaning well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, the unnamed mod's only interaction with me was the one that led to my complaint, and if Cerbrus were to make this claim, I'd say at least what their actions culminated in is evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 26):

This is in the context of the rude stuff you said about moderators in that other Meta question you posted, right? The irony is strong with this one.

Anyway… **having or stating an opinion about someone's behavior is not "rude or abusive" on this site**, especially when they were invited to share their opinion. You came to Meta because you wanted to hear other users' opinions. In other words, you opened up an issue for public discussion. Now, you don't like/agree with the opinions about the topic that were expressed by a particular user, so you're trying to flag them for moderator removal. Please stop.

The Code of Conduct is not to be used as a blunt instrument to prevent people from expressing opinions on Meta sites. As with [another recent complaint where a user described a post as "pedantic"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378113), this is (uh-oh, here we go again) silly. In fact, it's ridiculous.

If you did not want to hear people disagree with your opinions/tactics, then you probably shouldn't have given them a forum to do so.

A user's behavior can, according to another user's opinion, be "petty, childish, and a waste of everyone's time", and they can express this without violating any rules. Note that this is different from calling *a person* "petty [and] childish". As people, we all behave, from time to time, in ways that can be aptly described as "petty and childish". Calling out a behavior is not tantamount to slurring or attacking a person.

Had they said "that guy mklement0 is a petty child who keeps wasting our time", then that'd be a different story. I surely would have removed that, if not sent the author a warning about rudeness. Even on a Meta site, even in the context where discussion about a particular circumstance were invited.

Comment: Cody, please clarify if you're expressing a personal opinion here, or whether you're speaking as a moderator.

Comment: It can't be both, @mklement0 ?

Comment: Sure it can, @Larnu, but I'm trying to determine whether this answer is representative of what the moderator team as a whole think.

Comment: This answer was not written by a committee. Moderators are still individuals, even after being elected moderator. I am unable to draw the distinction that you are asking me to draw, and I'm not sure I would want to do so even if I could.

Comment: Understood, Cody, so is it fair to say that you're speaking _as a moderator_ here, and that what you expressed here guides your actions as a moderator?

Comment: I am explaining why I took the action that I did (declining your flag), and why I would continue to take similar actions again in the future. Considering I did/do those things as a moderator, I guess the answer to your question would be "yes"? Whether that represents the opinions of the entire moderator team, I cannot say, although I certainly have no reason to believe that I am an outlier here or have opinions that run counter to the rest of the team. Perhaps more importantly, I've seen many other mods and staff make similar decisions when it comes to discussions on Meta sites.

Comment: As for other mods: As stated in the OP, at least one moderator seems to implicitly agree that the statement was offensive; as quoted in the question: "you could have just flagged the comment and edited out the sentence". Just to spell it out: if there were nothing wrong with the sentence, there'd be no reason to edit it out.

Comment: I just noticed something, Cody, re "when it comes to discussions on Meta sites" - and I'm asking innocently: Does a different CoC / do different standards apply with respect to what is "rude or abusive" on Meta sites?

Comment: Somewhat, @mklement0. Not an entirely different CoC or anything like that, but the standards are different simply because, on Meta sites, discussions about users and user behavior is on-topic, whereas it wouldn't be anywhere else. So, a comment on the main site criticizing a user's behavior would be nearly instantly deleted as unfriendly, if not simply unnecessary, whereas that would be allowed on Meta. That's the distinction I was trying to make.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification, Cody. And to add a clarification on my end (a tl;dr of my answer): I'm certainly not objecting to discussing a user's behavior, I'm objecting to discussing it in the form of insults.

Comment: Under your view of what is rude and/or an insult, @mklement0, how can I tell you (or anyone, so as not to make this personal) exactly *why* I think a particular behavior is wrong? Wouldn't any attempt at criticizing a behavior become an insult? This is what I am struggling with. Naturally, I understand why you would be a bit miffed to read that someone thinks you are acting in a childish way; anyone would. But you'd be equally as miffed to read *any* criticism of your behavior! That, too, is simply human nature, just as is making mistakes.

Comment: Cody, the _why_ doesn't have to be an insult, and if it is, it is much more likely to generate ill will only; by contrast, _respectful_ criticism has a much better chance of getting heard. For instance, your feedback to me on the earlier post helped me see my part in the escalation. Not fun to realize when one has erred, but ultimately I appreciated that that blind spot was pointed out to me. If there even is a message in a given insult, it can be delivered without the offensive packaging. With your abstract interpretation of opinion and criticism, the category "rude or abusive" vanishes.

Comment: Also, Cody, just to ensure that no context is lost, I'd like to recap the evolution of your answer, (as partly reflected in the edit history):
You original hypothetical insult was (redacted to replace the original, explicit language): "that guy mklement0 is a petty, childish a-hole who keeps wasting our time"
In since-deleted comments, a user pointed out that this language wasn't necessary to illustrate your point; you responded that you needed a noun for you sentence; I suggested "hypocrite".
You then changed the hypothetical insult to "...  is a petty child ...".

Comment: Cody, it is implied by my answer, but let me spell it out: The [previous post you allude to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417570/45375) - both before and after
I revised the language to lessen the extent to which my original exasperation showed - contained  _no_ ad hominem allegations, only _complaints about_ such allegations by an - unknown to me - moderator (you may disagree with this characterization, but that's an entirely separate matter). Yet you characterize that post as "rude" in your answer, even though that category - by our own definition - doesn't apply. Please clarify.

Comment: Let me phrase it differently - and this is clearly a _debatable opinion_ that discusses your _behavior_: The above suggests that you judge what is rude by unstated biases, as evidenced by the following:
You deemed a complaint re perceived inappropriate moderator behavior rude, even though it criticized specific responses only.
Conversely, you condoned an obvious personal attack based on a sophistical distinction between an _explicit_ ad hominem 
argument and a _clearly implied_ one, going so far as condoning the latter _in general_.

Comment: Let me add another data point: "rude stuff you said about moderators" - plural - suggests that
you perceived - and emotionally reacted to - said post as an attack on _all_ moderators, even though the 
complaint was clearly about _one_
response from _one_ - unknown to me - moderator only.

Comment: You're wrong, an indirect personal attack is still a personal attack calling it an opinion doesn't change that, neither do opinions warrant personal attacks whether direct or indirect. Because there is a very strong correlation: it's always the same users mixing direct and indirect personal attacks who get away with it. Thus a CoC violation (but if it takes 600 mods to not realize that)...